# XAMPP - Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have reinstalled XAMPP for some reason and MySQL is not working, giving the following error in the console:

```
01:56:03  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
01:56:03  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
01:56:03  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
01:56:03  [mysql]   Check the "/xampp/mysql/data/mysql_error.log" file
01:56:03  [mysql]   and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
```

When checking the "/xampp/mysql/data/mysql_error.log" file I get:

```
130302  1:48:06  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130302  1:48:07 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1600324627
130302  1:48:07 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130302  1:48:07 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130302  1:48:07 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130302  1:51:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130302  1:51:12 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130302  1:51:12 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130302  1:51:12 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130302  1:51:12 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
130302  1:51:12 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130302  1:51:12 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130302  1:51:12  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
130302  1:51:13  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130302  1:51:14 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1600324627
130302  1:51:14 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130302  1:51:14 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130302  1:51:14 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130302  1:56:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130302  1:56:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130302  1:56:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130302  1:56:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130302  1:56:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
130302  1:56:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130302  1:56:01 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130302  1:56:01  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
130302  1:56:02  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130302  1:56:03 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1600324627
130302  1:56:03 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130302  1:56:03 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130302  1:56:03 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
```

That is just a part of the log, the full one is a bit too big.

Help?

Comment: If you're having the same issue, this might be the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859561/1956278

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your skype is open, Quit skype and try,

**or**

Go to your xampp/wamp installed, search for httpd.conf.
Open that file using textpad/notepad, search for Listen or 80 ,
update listen port to 8081 and save the file.
Restart xampp/wamp, start the servers.

**or**
 follow below steps in skype
[image]

Comment: i can't find advanced option on newest skype versions!

Comment: Any other solution?

Answer (score 82):

> Make sure you backup the mentioned folders before taking any action!

This worked for me,

1. Quit the XAMPP
2. Cut all files in **C:\xampp\mysql\backup**
3. Paste and replace files into **C:\xampp\mysql\data**
4. Run the XAMPP as administrator

Comment: thanks. This should also be a correct answer for those who have no port reguarding issues. Does anyone know why this happens - why XAMPP puts mysql data files in backup? Is it due to some kind of update?

Comment: Probably the best option, some say to change ports and it becomes messy, but this is simple and easy... I just copied and pasted files, kept the backup files same .

Comment: Make sure to have a backup of the data folder like data_old and create new folder data then paste from backup.

Comment: After doing that I am getting table doesn't exist in engine error.

Comment: You broke all my installations, now all websites require a new WordPress installation

Comment: Working and clean solution in 2022

Comment: amazing answer, that saved my day

Comment: As mentioned below in @hamid answer, if you had any tables in your database before, you will probably need to copy and paste an old `ibdata1`  file to recover them.

Comment: coming for the second time, it still worked

Answer (score 42):

In my case, I did two things:

1. moved `xampp/mysql/backup` files into `xampp/mysql/data`
2. RUN XAMPP as Administrator

It worked for me :)

---

EDIT:

> **IMPORTANT**: Make a backup copy of your `xampp/mysql/data` folder before trying this method, if your backup folder is out of sync with your data folder (which is often the case), you will overwrite that data with the backup folder and your tables will be lost.

Comment: and does not affect it your databases?

Comment: Do not do this guys, you will lost all of your tables, I did this, and now facing "Table dosen't exists in engine"

Comment: As said by @AlauddinAhmed. Now how to recover table data?

Comment: why this ans have much approve? please don't try this you will lose all table and all db.

Comment: You will lose all the data though MySQL will start working again. A useless method. Don't do. If you are very keen due to upvote, first take a backup of your backup folder.

Comment: Do not try this method. You will lose your database tables. If you want to try then just make a data folder backup first and then try it.

Comment: Don't do that . You will lost ibdata1 file , It means , you will lost your entire data.

Comment: Why some time i `moved xampp/mysql/backup files into xampp/mysql/data` worked, some time i `moved xampp/mysql/data files into xampp/mysql/backup` worked? lol

Answer (score 24):

First you need to keep copy of following somewhere in your hard disk.

> C:\xampp\mysql\backup
>
> C:\xampp\mysql\data

After that

> Copy every thing inside "C:\xampp\mysql\backup" and paste and replace it in
> "C:\xampp\mysql\data"

Now your mysql will work in phpmyadmin but your tables will show "Table not found in engine"

> For this you will have to go to the copy of "backup and data folders"
> which have created in your hard disk and there in the data folder copy
> "ibdata1" file and past and replace in the "C:\xampp\mysql\data".

Now your tables data will be available.

Comment: Best Answer, Thank you!

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This has to be the best answer. Thank you dude.

Comment: The best answer. It makes sense and it's straight forward

Comment: Great! This worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: This worked but user accounts not added when checked in phpmyadmin

Comment: Finally, I got the best and safest answer 100% tested by me and it works , Thank you so much.

Answer (score 14):

**Caution! Don't delete ibdata1 file!**

*Just follow these steps and its done.*

1. Rename the folder `C:\xampp\mysql\data` to `C:\xampp\mysql\data_old` (you can use any name)
2. Create a new folder `C:\xampp\mysql\data`
3. Copy the content that resides in `C:\xampp\mysql\backup` to the new `C:\xampp\mysql\data` folder
4. Copy all your database folders that are in `C:\xampp\mysql\data_old` to `C:\xampp\mysql\data` (skip the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders from `C:\xampp\mysql\data_old`)
5. Finally copy the ibdata1 file from `C:\xampp\mysql\data_old` and replace it inside `C:\xampp\mysql\data` folder
6. Now Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel

And its all done, Enjoy...

Comment: Perfect answer for Windows user, Thanks

Comment: I use this answer about every other month. Still works great on windows.

Answer (score 3):

1. Rename the folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old (you can use any name)
2. Create a new folder mysql/data Copy the content that resides in mysql/backup to the new mysql/data folder
3. Copy all your database folders that are in mysql/data_old to mysql/data (skipping the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders from data_old)
4. Finally copy the ibdata1 file from mysql/data_old and replace it inside the mysql/data folder
5. Start MySQL from the XAMPP control panel

Answer (score 2):

If Apache is running without any issue , and u find some blockage by system security settings , simply allow it instead of blocking or closing the dialog box. 
And change the port number for MySQL to 3607 as it was before 3606 . 
It worked for me .

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this,

Go to your XAMPP folder,

> XAMPP -> mysql -> bin -> "my.ini"

After opening `my.ini` configuration file, Replace `3306` with `3308` in couple of places, because `3308` is a free port.

> XAMPP -> php -> "php.ini"

Do the same as you did in "my.ini" file which is changing port `3306` to `3308`.

Then, restart the XAMPP server.

It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There may be MySQL server installed previously in your computer try to uninstall that and start MySQL at the XAMPP This solved mine

Answer (score 1):

I am new to XAMPP, but I find that a combination of these suggestions works best (At least on Windows 8.1 with the latest version of XAMPP. Note that the computer I tested this on, also had skype).

First logon to skype and navigate to "Tools < Options < Advanced < Connection."
Then check the box that says "Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections." Save, close, and quit skype.

Next, on your XAMPP control panel, click "config < my.ini" and change lines 19 and 27 (should have port = 3306) from "3306" to "3307."

Also, you will need to navigate to xampp < phpMyAdmin < config.inc and change line 27, which should like something like this:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

You will need to add "3307" as follows:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';

Now, open your browser and you should see the xampp page when you type in "localhost."
Additionally, if this is your first time using xampp, you may see a warning about your lack of password (highlighted in pink) on your localhost/phpmyadmin/ page. This is easily remedied by going to the "user accounts" tab in phpmyadmin, clicking on "edit privileges" and entering password. Remember to save the hashed version of any and all passwords you create as we will use this next! -I opened a notepad and saved (and numbered) them. Note that phpMyadmin will notify you of when you are changing the password for your current session (this will be displayed at the top of your phpMyadmin page and is very important, as you will need THAT specific hashed version of your password).

Next, you will need to navigate to the following location "xampp < phpMyAdmin < config.inc" on your computer and open and edit the file with a text editor. You will want to put in the hashed version of your password between the single quotes for password and change "AllowNoPassword" from true to false.

And, that ought to do it.

Answer (score 1):

the true way is **RECONFIGURE**  your app.with setup of **MYSQL** .you can open your setup again and **change port from 3306 to 3307**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to go to *C:\xampp\mysql\data* and delete all *files* (not folders) but keep **ibdata1** and **my.ini**. Restartet XAMPP, everything running again.

Hope that helps someone - had to look for hours before finding that!

Answer (score 0):

I would simply try reinstalling XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

one reason I found ( and not mentioned in addition to other answers given in this site on the similar problem ) was by going to task manager in windows and stopping the mysqld which was running already and prevented mysql server from starting.

Answer (score 0):

You must:

- Close the xampp
- Go to the folder where you installed it, if in (c:) may be something like C:\xampp\ , access folder **C:\xampp\mysql\data**
- Delete the file **ibdata1**
- Starts XAMPP again.

Comment: That did not help me with the same problem.

Comment: Don't delete *ibdata1*, You will have to copy data from backup and at that you will need this file to restore your database.

Comment: Not working any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is just open your mysql configuration directive file **my.ini** present inside the folder **C:\xampp\mysql\bin** and change the information related to the ports, usually some programs occupy the port no. 3306 as a result of that it stops working, Now you follow two steps to make it working.

```
enter code here

    Step-1. Search for ['client'],  you can see some thing like this

            [client] 
            # password       = your_password 
            port            = 3306
            socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
 Now in the port section remove 3306 and add port = 3306 > 3307 as shown   below.

            [client] 
            # password       = your_password 
            port            = 3306 > 3307
            socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


    Step -2. Similarly Search for  ['mysqld'], you can see something like this 

            [mysqld]
            port= 3306
            socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
            basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
            tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
            datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
            pid_file = "mysql.pid"
            # enable-named-pipe
            key_buffer = 16M
            max_allowed_packet = 1M
            sort_buffer_size = 512K
            net_buffer_length = 8K
            read_buffer_size = 256K
            read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
            myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
            log_error = "mysql_error.log"


            Now here change the port number 3306 to 3307 and add a line "innodb_force_recovery = 1" exactly as shown below.


            [mysqld]
            port= 3307
            socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
            basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
            tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
            datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
            pid_file = "mysql.pid"
            # enable-named-pipe
            key_buffer = 16M
            max_allowed_packet = 1M
            sort_buffer_size = 512K
            net_buffer_length = 8K
            read_buffer_size = 256K
            read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
            myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
            log_error = "mysql_error.log"
            innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

Thats it, restart you mysql service, it will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that searched and pressed on this link, i solved it by simply searching for mysql notifier and stop mysql from running there, Then run mysql in xampp again and it runs. why this works ? iam not expert, but i think it is easy : port was taken already by mysql notifier so had to stop it there and run it here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case : 
I have just replaced

```
....xampp/mysql/backup files
```

into

```
**xampp/mysql/data**
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you inistalled mysql Independently
you can stop mysql service if running 
no one of these answers are worked for me
this work for me

Answer (score 0):

Well first thing ,, I know its late so I dont know if anyone will upvote it but oh well its okay,, 
secondly,  uninstalling xampp might not do you any good because the process using the port 3306 (Mysql's default port) will still be running somewhere on your system. might be skype, but might not be skype.

so the best way would be to find out which process is using port 3306, and then terminate the process.

so to find out which process is using port 3306, open command prompt, and type

```
netstat -n -o -a
```

you will get a screen like 
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcHKC.png)

Then look for the address with port number 3306
and find out the PID corresponding to that.

Then simply open a command prompt as administrator and type

```
taskkill /F /PID 1234
```

replace 1234 with your respective PID.
Then you can try starting mysql and it will work.

---

And now if you are lazy to do this step all over again when restarting the computer,,,

you can simply use the following batch script to terminate the process automatically and enjoy :)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set "port=3306"
for /f "tokens=1,4,5" %%a in (
    'netstat -aon ^| findstr /r /c:"[TU][CD]P[^[]*\[::\]:%port%"'
) do if "%%a"=="UDP" (taskkill /F /PID %%b) else (taskkill /f /PID %%c)
endlocal
pause
```

save it as anything.bat and run it everytime you want to use mysql. :)

---

Answer (score 0):

**
->   "xampp->mysql->data" cut all files from data folder and paste to another folder

-> now restart mysql

-> paste all folders from your folder to myslq->data folder

and also paste ib_logfile0.ib_logfile1 , ibdata1 into data folder from your folder.

your database and your data is now available in phpmyadmin..**

Comment: adding explanation to your answer will help

Comment: Create a folder in any drive where you can copy all files of mysql->data folder, then clean the data folder and restart mysql from xampp control panel ,.    Then move all folders only not files from your copy folder to mysql->data folder and move files ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 , ibdata1 from copy folder to data folder so your databases and tables and table's data is available in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

**I did all methods but didn't find the perfect solution!**

- Install Laragon instead of Xampp , You will pray for me.

Comment: Apply this solution...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66594635/9331130

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the folder C:\xampp\mysql\data to C:\xampp\mysql\data_old (you can use any name)
2. Create a new folder C:\xampp\mysql\data
3. Copy the content that resides in C:\xampp\mysql\backup to the new C:\xampp\mysql\data folder
4. Copy all your database folders that are in C:\xampp\mysql\data_old to C:\xampp\mysql\data (skip the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders from C:\xampp\mysql\data_old)
5. Finally copy the ibdata1 file from C:\xampp\mysql\data_old and replace it inside C:\xampp\mysql\data folder

Now Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel

This helps me!!

Answer (score -3):

just run your xammp as an administrator, it works