# InnoDB: Cannot open table

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm creating a web application in PHP, MySQL, and Apache. I'm getting these error when running the application. Installed php with XAMPP. I tried reinstalling but not working...

---

**Error Log File:**

```
2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

2013-08-09 16:53:07 125c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:-xampp-mysql-data-ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:-xampp-mysql-data-ibdata1 size to 10 MB

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:-xampp-mysql-data-ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:-xampp-mysql-data-ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:-xampp-mysql-data-ib_logfile101 to C:-xampp-mysql-data-ib_logfile0

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45781

2013-08-09 16:53:07 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new

2013-08-09 16:53:08 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created

2013-08-09 16:53:08 6208 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.

2013-08-09 16:53:08 6208 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.

2013-08-09 16:53:08 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created

2013-08-09 16:53:08 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.11 started; log sequence number 0

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 67e94d01-0103-11e3-8977-8c89a5f60f07.

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Note] IPv6 is available.

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Note] - '::' resolves to '::';

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_master_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See "Innodb-troubleshooting.html" for how you can resolve the problem.

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' cannot be opened.

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_worker_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_relay_log_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' cannot be opened.

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events

2013-08-09 16:53:09 6208 [Note] c:-xampp-mysql-bin-mysqld.exe: ready for connections.

Version: '5.6.11' socket: '' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

2013-08-09 16:57:31 1c4c InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.

2013-08-09 16:57:31 1c4c InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.

2013-08-09 16:57:31 1c4c InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "Test_Tb"."login_info" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

2013-08-09 17:01:52 11c0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:-xampp-mysql-data-ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:-xampp-mysql-data-ibdata1 size to 10 MB

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:-xampp-mysql-data-ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB

2013-08-09 17:01:52 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:-xampp-mysql-data-ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB

2013-08-09 17:01:53 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:-xampp-mysql-data-ib_logfile101 to C:-xampp-mysql-data-ib_logfile0

2013-08-09 17:01:53 7560 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45781

2013-08-09 17:01:53 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new

2013-08-09 17:01:53 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.11 started; log sequence number 0

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] IPv6 is available.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] - '::' resolves to '::';

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_master_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See "innodb-troubleshooting.html" for how you can resolve the problem.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' cannot be opened.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_worker_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See "innodb-troubleshooting.html" for how you can resolve the problem.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_relay_log_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See ""innodb-troubleshooting.html"" for how you can resolve the problem.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' cannot be opened.

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events

2013-08-09 17:01:54 7560 [Note] c:-xampp-mysql-bin-mysqld.exe: ready for connections.

Version: '5.6.11' socket: '' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

2013-08-09 17:02:05 7560 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table Test_Tb/login_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See "innodb-troubleshooting.html" for how you can resolve the problem.
```

Answer (score 2):

exit Xampp server,delete the ibdata1 file in  C:\xampp\mysql\data.
You might want to do a mysqldump before.

Comment: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_table_stats.ibd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly