# Xampp mysql cant run database i already created

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

i installed xampp and planing to use the apache server and the mysql server.
while running the first time, i load the database from phpmyadmin, and it loads fine. after i work with my app i check that the db is updated and it is.

1. after closing the servers and returning to them later, i have problem to start the mysql server, so i found some helpfull links and followed them...

[XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/fixedxampp-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

although it did helped but im not sure the issue is the port. what worked for me is deleting the ibdata1 file.
so why cant i run the mysql the second time? each time i have to delete the file?

2. following question one, i have problems updating my databases in phpmyadmin, and have to delete the db manually from c:\xampp\mysql\data\"db_name"
   and then loading it again through phpmyadmin. im sure this is the wrong way but not deleting it will mess up the db so dont have any other choice at the moment.

please note there are 2 separate questions, but the issue is the same.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean "I have problems updating my databases in phpmyadmin"? Describe the problems.

Comment: well, after following the procedure i described, i delete ibdata1 file, so i can start the mysql server (in the second time) but then when i use myphpadmin, it shows me the db "foo" but with no entries that i have inserted into it. trying to drop the db with phpmyadmin gives me error (no 41) saying cant rm_dir "foo" so i have to go to the db manually in c:\xampp... in order to delete it. as i sayed before im sure this isnt how it supposed to work, just cant find any good solution over the web.