# mysql won't start on xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

This is the error message i get when trying to start mysql on xampp, i was just using it last night but it wont start today, any help appreciated.

```
12:03:07  [mysql]       Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:03:07  [mysql]       This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:03:07  [mysql]       improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:03:07  [mysql]       Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:03:07  [mysql]       the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:03:07  [mysql]       If you need more help, copy and post this
12:03:07  [mysql]       entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: could you add the mysql error log to your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have a another mysql service running on same port **3306**.
You can find the service panel by

```
Start -> Run, type in services.msc, click OK.
```

Once you find it, shut it down and try starting xampp's mysql service.

Answer (score 0):

Probably  you install wamp recently. You need to change mysql port on wamp server e.g on 3008. And restart your xampp server.