# Xampp MySQL error?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Today I've installed XAMPP in C:/xampp.
And I'm getting an error while trying to run MYSQL like this:

```
12:29:29  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
12:29:30  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
12:29:30  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:29:30  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:29:30  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:29:30  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:29:30  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:29:30  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:29:30  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

And also here's the copy of the error log file:

```
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-02-08 12:29:30 34c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: File 'C:\xampp\tmp\ib9241.tmp' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2014-02-08 12:29:30 34c  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Binlog end
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-02-08 12:29:30 3208 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

I've been trying to install Joomla using Xampp.

Xampp version >> 3.2.1 Compiled: May 7th 2013
Joomla version >> 3.2.2 (Stable Full Package)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Looks a little like a file permission problem. But I have next to now experience with MS-Windows systems, sorry.

Comment: I think this SO answer will work for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/18162264/817365

Comment: Check what's wrong with `File 'C:\xampp\tmp\ib9241.tmp' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)` Maybe you started the xampp once as admin and the file is now not accessible fot other users.

Comment: Deleting that file didn't do anything but I'll try to reinstall it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql uses port 3306, do you have any other programs running on this port? If you do, shut them down and then try starting mysql again. If you can, go to http://www.apachefriends.org/download.html and download the latest version of Xampp and reinstall it, it may be that you are missing a file or have a corrupted file. You can copy your htdocs folder to your desktop so you don't loose anything and then copy it back. Good luck!

Comment: If you look at the error log, you see a file access exception. So the port is not a issue.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that. You could try exit Xampp server,
go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory,
delete the ibdata1 file,
restart xampp server. Or just re-install xampp.

Comment: I did delete that file but it's still not working. I think I'll go for reinstalling the XAMPP thanks BTW! :)

Comment: Try running xampp control panel as administrator. It is most likely something blocking it on your pc. Try allowing it through the firewall

Answer (score 9):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing these 2 log files from the mysql folder

```
/mysql/data/ib_logfile0 
/mysql/data/ib_logfile1
```

I hope it helps anybody having the same issue.