# Error in starting mysqls server using xampp

Tags: mysql

I am not able to start MYSQL server>
This is the error

```
    7:16:07 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
     7:16:07 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port,   missing    dependencies, 
   7:16:07 PM  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
  7:16:07 PM  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
```

Log file is

```
   2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-01-23 19:16:06 418 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
2015-01-23 19:16:06 4512 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Binlog end
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

I am a newbie in Mysql and I am using xampp to run the sql server.This is  my first installation of xampp.kindly help me.what should I do to solve this error

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly ?

Comment: ya I tried  .Now i got Another log I have edited the log

Comment: Have you posted the correct section of the log? I don't see any actual errors, and the time of the error is 19:16 whereas the time in the error log is 18:33 (assuming they are from the same day even).

Comment: Can you provide more information? Perhaps you show us how you are trying to start MySQL, as well as what log file you are see those messages in?

Comment: I have edited the question with recent  log

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the error:

```
2015-01-23 19:16:07 4512 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101
```

clearly the server process cannot create the InnoDB log file, so it is aborting. There could be a number of reasons why this is happening, but I'd check your available disk space, and check that the file doesn't already exist with the wrong permissions/owner.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-creating-innodb.html for additional checks.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, resolved with php_memory_limit being to high, make it 256M,
This Worked for me.