# XAMPP - Error MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I open XAMPP and click start MySQL button and it gives me an error I had it started just before but now it isn't working.

> 13:06:29  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 13:06:29 [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>
> 13:06:29  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 13:06:29  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 13:06:29  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 13:06:29  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 13:06:29  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

Logs:
[enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/u3YyzXrE)

Comment: Any chance MySQL is still running from "just before"? You'd probably have a port conflict then, as it says in the error message. Otherwise, have you checked the logs?

Comment: Actually, it its to blame of ports because:

http://pastebin.com/5g116rCw

Yesterday, I installed the MySQL Workbench.

Comment: you can check this answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859561/4213741

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to path `C:\xampp\mysql\data`
2. Search  `multi-master.info`
3. Delete `multi-master.info`