# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

XAMPP's control panel displays error as

> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>   14:09:43  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

Text in `mysql_error.log` is

```
3812 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 1604 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is        DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
[Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
[Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
       [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
 2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
  [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
   [ERROR] Aborting

2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Binlog end
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
  2015-04-15 14:09:43 3812 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Can you indicate what solutions you have tried already?

Comment: I have deleted ibdata1 file from C:\xampp\mysql\data and also changed the port number.. created backup file for ibdata1 instead of deleting it

Comment: This because Port:80 Used by another Program. Two solution there. 1. change the port some thing like 85. or 2. If you install SKYPE that also use port 80. in skype settings you can change that.

Comment: I've faced the same problem as "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly" when I try to load my project in my localhost.

Comment: Finally I got the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fix the problem without losing your data you need to restore your database from backup just follow below steps carefuly and it will works !!

1. Rename the folder `xampp/mysql/data` to `xampp/mysql/data_backup`
2. Create a new folder `xampp/mysql/data`
3. Copy the content that resides in `xampp/mysql/backup` to the new
   `xampp/mysql/data` folder
4. Copy all your database folders that are in `xampp/mysql/data_backup` to `xampp/mysql/data`

*Important:* Do not copy the mysql, ***performance_schema***, and ***phpmyadmin*** folders from `xampp/mysql/data_bk`

5.Copy the ibdata1 file from `xampp/mysql/data_backup` and replace
it inside `xampp/mysql/data` folder

5.FINALLY!! Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel again

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding this problem,
you can follow some steps which are given below:

1. At first you should stop "Apache" and "MySQL" in your "xampp
   control panel".
2. Go to the path: `C:\xampp\mysql\backup`
   Copy here everything
3. Go to the path: `C:\xampp\mysql\data`
   And paste it here everything
4. Here you will see a pop-up: Replace or Skip Files
   Click `Replace the files in the destination`
5. Now you can start "Apache" and "MySQL" without any hassle.

Hopefully, it will work properly.

Comment: I tried your solution. Now I have a different issue, can you help? Here is my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78059549/wordpress-error-after-solving-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly