# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly;

Tags: mysql, xampp, local, shutdown

I spend a few hours trying to run mysql in xampp, but it's still not working. Tried some other answers on fora but with no succes. Hope anyone can help to fix this.

Xampp:

```
23:36:06  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
23:36:06  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
23:36:06  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
23:36:06  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
23:36:06  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
23:36:06  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
23:36:06  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

mysql_error.log

```
2016-03-08 23:36:05 1aa0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
160308 23:36:05 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
160308 23:36:05 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160308 23:36:05 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
160308 23:36:05 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
160308 23:36:05 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160308 23:36:05 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
160308 23:36:05 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
160308 23:36:05 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160308 23:36:05 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160308 23:36:06 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
160308 23:36:06 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
160308 23:36:06 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 1665234
160308 23:36:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160308 23:36:06 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Look at this
[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18162264/4464410). it's probably the same problem.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, but unfortunately.. already tried without succes

Answer (score 0):

@APRZ I'm don't use XAMPP... Mayby install Apache, PHP and MySQL from binaries for Windows i'm always do that it's work excellent.

Comment: Well, sometimes happens... From now you start doing backups your databases :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reinstalling xampp on an other pc, using these data files and imported the database from the live version. Now it's working fine.

I lost the local data but was not necessary for me.