# MySql On XAMPP Shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql

I just start mysql but there is some error. I have config my.cnf and descrease innodb_buffer_pool_size to 64 MB but nothing happend.

```
/*this showed in xampp*/
 9:34:39 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    9:34:39 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    9:34:39 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    9:34:39 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    9:34:39 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    9:34:39 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
    9:34:39 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

then i see to the mysql error log. it shows.

```
/*this showed in error log*/
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-05-19 00:34:02 c4c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1665234
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-05-19 00:34:02 3968 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-05-19 00:53:44 2936 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
```

how should i fix it?

Comment: exit Xampp server
go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
delete the ibdata1 file
restart xampp server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly try to apply the changes mentioned in the other comments to prevent future unexpected shutdowns.

Comment: i've just try to delete ibdata1, but the error still showed up..
i just uninstall it then it works well.. thanks for answer..

Comment: in your case you should always keep a backup of /var/lib/mysql folder until you figure out what's causing the issue. xampp also conflicts with other applications that are already installed on your desktop or server.