# I can't run xampp - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I have two version of xampp in my Laptop version 7(good and working) and xampp that not working v5.6.28. I tried a lot of tweaks, I changed the port mysql.ini, httpd, etc. Deleting not important files in mysql data. Can anyone please help me this problem.

```
2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in 
future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the 
InnoDB's internal memory allocator.

2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer   pool pages
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows    
interlocked functions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB  
(http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
 2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary  distribution
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1835037
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Sometimes it stacked up at "attempting to start mysql app..." and sometimes this error occur.

```
 Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
2:43:47 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
2:43:47 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
2:43:47 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:43:47 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:43:47 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
2:43:47 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18022809/5447994)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly check this link

Comment: I already delete the ibdata1 and restart, run as administrator not working as well

Comment: restart your xampp then

Comment: Do you have to run both instances of xampp simultaneously?

Comment: @SajeshBahing No, but I think because of the root folder name, I changed it instead of xampp to xampp-5.6.28. I just change all the word name xampp to xamp-5.6.28 it work but the version that i'm using still 7.0.13

Answer (score 0):

you can use wamp server it`s alternative of xampp and you can run both php 5.6 and php7 
in new version 
http://www.wampserver.com/en/