# Cannot use XAMPP

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I have just downloaded XAMPP but as soon as I open it I get two errors:

```
   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
   21:43:43  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing    dependencies, 
   21:43:43  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
   21:43:43  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
   21:43:43  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
   21:43:43  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
   21:43:43  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

And :

```
   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
   21:43:56  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
   21:43:56  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
   21:43:56  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
   21:43:56  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
   21:43:56  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
   21:43:56  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

I like answers at [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly) and various other places but they dont help me in any way
I am not using Skype. I had installed wampserver before and have just uninstalled it after I read it interferes with the working of XAMPP
The entire log is :

```
    Running with Administrator rights - good!
    21:43:39  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\users\android.desktop-s6p9r3v.001\xamppp\"
    21:43:39  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
    21:43:39  [main]    All prerequisites found
    21:43:39  [main]    Initializing Modules
    21:43:39  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
    21:43:39  [main]    Control Panel Ready
    21:43:42  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache service...
    21:43:42  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
    21:43:43  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
    21:43:43  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
    21:43:43  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    21:43:43  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    21:43:43  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    21:43:43  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    21:43:43  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
    21:43:43  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
    21:43:51  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
    21:43:51  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
    21:43:56  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
    21:43:56  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    21:43:56  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    21:43:56  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    21:43:56  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    21:43:56  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    21:43:56  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
    21:43:56  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

I did netstat -a and I got this result:

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:902            DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:912            DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49669          DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49670          DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8092         DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:30000        DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49671        DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.20.1:139       DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.43.241:139     DESKTOP-S6P9R3V:0      LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49696   hk2sch130021327:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49811   151.101.1.69:http      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49826   151.101.1.69:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49909   151.101.1.69:http      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49936   192.0.73.2:https       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49940   a23-6-212-55:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49943   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49949   104.16.109.18:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49952   104.16.109.18:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49953   104.16.109.18:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49954   104.16.109.18:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49960   a122-252:https         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49972   93.184.216.169:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49973   93.184.216.169:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49974   209.17.68.209:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49975   209.17.68.209:http     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49976   209.17.68.209:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49979   93.184.216.169:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49981   93.184.216.169:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49983   pixel:https            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49987   209.17.68.209:http     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49988   209.17.68.209:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49989   209.17.68.209:http     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49990   209.17.68.209:http     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49991   209.17.68.209:http     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49992   209.17.68.209:http     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49995   server-54-230-190-236:http  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49996   server-54-230-190-65:http  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:49999   server-54-230-190-236:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50000   ec2-54-183-175-145:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50001   server-54-230-190-65:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50007   93.184.216.169:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50010   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50011   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50012   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50013   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50015   146.20.129.13:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50016   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50017   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50018   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50019   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50020   static:http            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50021   175:http               TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50023   ec2-46-137-212-246:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50028   ec2-107-20-134-7:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50029   a173-223-209-71:http   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50030   a173-223-209-71:http   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50032   a173-223-209-71:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50033   ec2-46-137-212-246:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50035   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50036   static:http            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50037   ec2-107-20-134-7:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50039   ec2-52-192-132-119:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50041   ec2-52-8-242-15:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50044   103.229.206.54:http    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50045   103.229.206.54:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50049   159.127.41.108:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50050   159.127.41.108:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50052   ec2-52-192-132-119:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50053   ec2-52-8-242-15:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50055   103.229.206.54:http    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50056   ec2-23-22-253-187:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50059   146.20.128.49:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50061   ec2-54-179-142-156:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50062   maa03s18-in-f2:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50063   maa03s18-in-f2:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50064   maa03s18-in-f2:http    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50070   ec2-54-243-109-164:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50072   104.244.42.131:https   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50073   c0:http                TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50075   ec2-50-19-219-71:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50076   ec2-54-243-109-164:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50077   ec2-50-19-219-71:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50078   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50079   static:http            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50080   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50081   static:http            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50082   static:http            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50083   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50084   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50085   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50086   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50087   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50090   173:http               TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50093   convserv-23:http       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50095   103.15.158.193:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50096   a:http                 ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50097   a:http                 TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50099   convserv-23:http       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50101   103.15.158.193:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50102   a:http                 TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50103   ec2-54-255-228-44:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50104   ec2-52-34-195-25:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50105   ec2-52-76-100-64:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50110   ec2-52-76-100-64:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50112   ec2-54-254-237-54:http  LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50114   ec2-54-254-237-54:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50115   server-54-230-190-113:http  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50116   server-54-230-190-113:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50117   server-54-230-190-113:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50119   151.101.193.108:http   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50122   175:http               TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50124   151.101.193.108:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50125   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50128   ec2-54-215-82-220:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50129   a173-223-209-71:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50130   static:http            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50131   ec2-54-255-228-44:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50132   ec2-52-34-195-25:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50134   pixel:http             TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50135   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50136   static:http            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50138   175:http               TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50139   104.16.26.35:http      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50140   104.16.25.235:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50144   104.16.25.235:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50147   presentation-hkg1:http  LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50156   s-prd-umpxl-adcom-scd-blue-b:http  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50157   unknown:http           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50159   s-prd-umpxl-adcom-scd-blue-b:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50160   206-140:http           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50161   206-140:http           TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50162   unknown:http           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50165   unknown:http           FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50166   unknown:http           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50167   206-140:http           TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50168   unknown:http           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50170   unknown:http           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50171   s-prd-umpxl-adcom-scd-blue-b:http  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50172   s-prd-umpxl-adcom-scd-blue-b:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50173   111.221.29.30:http     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50181   ec2-54-254-189-128:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50184   211:http               TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50185   tp00-hk2:http          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50186   tp00-hk2:http          TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50187   a23-6-218-226:http     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50188   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50190   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50192   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50198   70:https               ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50199   38.106.10.132:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50200   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50201   unknown:https          TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50202   sjc-delivery-9:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50203   70:https               ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50204   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50205   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50211   webserver:http         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50215   175:https              TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50216   a23-6-212-55:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50217   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50218   static:http            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50219   static:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50223   a:http                 TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50224   a173-223-209-71:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50225   ec2-52-76-100-64:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50226   ec2-46-137-212-246:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50227   103.15.158.193:http    FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50228   103.15.158.193:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50229   8.39.37.45:http        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50230   8.39.37.45:http        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50234   ec2-52-192-132-119:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50235   nfy-rubicon-hk2:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50236   nfy-rubicon-hk2:http   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50239   node-210-160-193-174:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50241   node-210-160-193-173:http  FIN_WAIT_1
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50244   ec2-54-154-26-148:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50245   151.101.194.49:http    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50246   151.101.194.49:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50247   nfy-rubicon-hk2:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50248   151.101.194.49:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50249   ec2-54-154-26-148:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50251   node-210-160-193-174:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50254   ads:http               TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50260   151.101.192.166:http   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50261   151.101.192.166:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50263   ads:http               TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50265   151.101.192.166:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50267   103.67.200.188:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50269   ec2-52-220-84-102:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50270   103.67.200.188:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50271   104.25.239.100:http    LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50272   maa03s20-in-f42:http   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50274   104.25.239.100:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50275   ec2-54-254-237-54:http  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50276   maa03s20-in-f42:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50277   maa03s18-in-f35:http   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50278   ec2-52-197-225-32:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50279   ec2-52-197-225-32:http  LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50280   ec2-52-197-225-32:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50283   pixel:https            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50287   pixel:https            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50293   stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50295   ec2-54-254-237-54:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50296   ec2-54-254-237-54:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50297   104.16.109.18:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50298   104.16.109.18:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50299   104.16.109.18:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50300   104.16.109.18:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50301   104.16.109.18:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50302   pixel:http             TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50304   pixel:http             TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50305   server-54-230-190-65:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50306   server-54-230-190-65:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.43.241:50307   151.101.1.69:http      TIME_WAIT
```

I does not mean anything to me

Comment: Check if the default Ports are used by another service: netstat -a

Comment: Are you running Skype? When I used to run xampp, Skype was taking the ports needed by Xampp.

Comment: No I don't  But I am using the 32-bit model on my 64-bit windows 10