# MYSQL can't start due to unexpected error

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I open XAMPP and click start MySQL button and it gives me an error I had it started just before but now it isn't working

Here is the errors from log file please help me out.

```
2017-08-01 23:43:15 2790 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-08-01 23:43:15 10128 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: No brother it is not duplicated it was working just fine i restarted my system and after that this happens

Comment: Hey @Mohsin same problem here today with me, can have you find any helpful answer. Please help

Comment: Hey @Mohsin i found one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58415189/11554604) of this problem, i hope this solution worked for you because me too facing this problem **after restarting my System**

Answer (score 0):

based on this answer 
[XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/18162264#18162264)

1. exit Xampp server
2. go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
3. delete the **ibdata1** file
4. restart xampp server
5. It should work

Comment: I have already tried this solution but the issue is still there. I have also tried by changing the port but it didn;t help me either