# Can't run XAMPP - MySql

Tags: xampp

When I try to start XAMPP - MySql it doesn't work. 
I've already tried to fix it, but I couldn't find any actual solution, I hope you can find what's wrong with it.

There's the log:

```
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2019-06-26  9:08:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45786
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\user' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Index for table '.\mysql\user' is corrupt; try to repair it
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [ERROR] Couldn't repair table: mysql.user
2019-06-26  9:08:36 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Index for table 'user' is corrupt; try to repair it
```

Comment: See [ApacheFriends.org](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=78295) for bug description

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This is as a result of some files in *C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql* getting corrupted.

**Solution**:

1. Back up *C:\xampp\mysql\data*
2. Copy all file *C:\xampp\mysql\backup*
3. Paste and replace existing file in: *C:\xampp\mysql\data*, **except** for the *ibdata1* file.
   Leaving *ibdata1* will help against table does not exist error.

Comment: Thank you Tobiloba this still works on XAMPP version 8 in 2023, you saved me

Comment: This is hard to understand. 3. paste and replace exisiting file where from to where???

Answer (score 45):

The solution was just a

```
Copy From ...xampp/mysql/backup/... of all files and paste into .../xampp/mysql/data/  -> you will lost your data

Just copy the folder From ...xampp/mysql/backup/ & Paste into .../xampp/mysql/data/  -> this will help to run Mysql & existing database is working
```

Comment: Can someone give an explanation of this?

Comment: Thanks , this worked for me, but i copied **only folders** from backup Because when i copied and pasted all of from backup then mysql works fine but data is lost from my databases

Comment: I suggest to everyone to try Laragon is really more powerful, https://laragon.org/

Comment: You will lose your databases. Check Tobiloba's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61284676/799176)

Comment: All schema is lost, this makes xampp works but all data is lost!

Answer (score 20):

That happened to me before and the solution was very simple for that.
please Read all steps carefully :

1. Make a backup for this folder **C:\xampp\mysql\data** (make sure your backup folder's name is not **backup**) .
2. Now Copy all *files/folders* from **C:\xampp\mysql\backup** except **ibdata1** to avoid error of table does not exist .
3. Paste all copied *files/folders* to **C:\xampp\mysql\data**

Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: sloved.  Haha.  :-)

Comment: @SteveStilson haha

Comment: After 3 hours of working your answer saved me. Thank you soooo much..

Answer (score 12):

copy all the file and folder from xampp/mysql/backup/ and paste it to xampp/mysql/data/. If asked for replace than click on replace all

Comment: While I did that another issue come while I'm using Wordpress and it's asked me to install the wordpress again

Comment: it works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 7):

@tobiloba's Solution is a temporary one. I had the similar problem. and which will be solved temporarily with his solution. But on next time of mysql start. it failed. As I need to keep my data as well as open the mysql server to run it.

Open your my.conf from **xampp/mysql/bin/my.conf** and find this two lines.

```ini
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10M
```

change this to 30M 0r 50MB. and than

```ini
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:20M:autoextend
```

change this too

```ini
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:60M:autoextend
```

For me it solved the problem permanently and keep my existing data alive and works fine after that.

Comment: in my case, the file location is bin/my.ini, just in case you don't find the my.conf file.

Comment: However, does it still use a lot of data after a year?

Answer (score 2):

This solution will help to secure your existing database.

```
Just copy the folder From ...xampp/mysql/backup/ & Paste into .../xampp/mysql/data/  -> this will help to run Mysql & existing database is working
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply edit this line from my.ini:

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit=128M -> choose size you want.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I did a backup of the data folder, then copied the files and folders in /backup/ to /data/ and the service started successfully. I did not have to copy anything from my backed up data except for ibdata1 without which complained about tables not existing.

Answer (score 0):

Delete or Move the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 to a backup folder.. and try to restart Mysql
That will restore those files and mysql should run without loosing any data.