# XAMPP – MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: xampp

I've just installed XAMPP, and when I try to start my Apache and MySQL in the XAMPP Control Panel, I now get the following errors:

19:27:08  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
19:27:08  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
19:27:08  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
19:27:08  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
19:27:08  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
19:27:08  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
19:27:08  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums

InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-03-17 19:10:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-03-17 19:10:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-03-17 19:10:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-03-17 19:10:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-03-17 19:10:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-03-17 19:10:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-03-17 19:10:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-17 19:10:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2020-03-17 19:10:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-03-17 19:10:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-03-17 19:10:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-03-17 19:10:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-17 19:10:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-03-17 19:10:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-03-17 19:10:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 171
2020-03-17 19:10:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-17 19:10:22 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-03-17 19:10:22 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

Answer (score 1):

This is as a result of some files in C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql getting corrupted.

first of all, try to end the task in task manager mysqlid.exe end and start again MySQL in Xampp, if there is the same error try this below solution. please backup that data.

Solution:

1. Back up C:\xampp\mysql\data
2. Copy all file C:\xampp\mysql\backup
3. Paste and replace existing file in: C:\xampp\mysql\data, except for
   the ibdata1 file. Leaving ibdata1 will help against table does not
   exist error.
   this solution work for me its [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767200/cant-run-xampp-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the ports were used by some application on your windows.

You can change the port:

Go to your xampp folder, find the mysql.cnf or mysql.ini to change the port 3306 to others

Then restart again.

Comment: I've tried...  but MySQL still shutdown unexpectedly.

Comment: @余雅馨 same error? May I know have you changed the port of  mysql.cnf?

Answer (score 0):

If in your XAMPP control panel when you try to start the mysql it starts by getting PID and port number(3306) and then shutdowns unexpectedly.

The solution which worked for me is just go to your  "C:\xampp\mysql\bin" directory (If you have installed on other location go to bin folder of mysql in that) and doubleclick the
mysqld.exe file.It will start working.

It also works using cmd (If you have installed XAMMP in other directory change the path accordingly.)

> cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin

> mysqld

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps this may resolve your issue

1. Close Xampp.
2. Go to \xampp\mysql\backup.
3. Copy all files in directory except ibdata1.
4. Go to \xampp\mysql\data.
5. Paste the files that you copied from \xampp\mysql\ backup (Replace the files when asked).
6. Start Xampp.