# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. on xampp-control

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, database-connection

I'm running windows 10 and when I try to start my MySQL from xampp-control i'm getting an error saying `Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.`

I tried several solution like killing the `mysqld` process from the taskmanager and deleting `ibdata1` file but still getting the same issue...

following is my error log, please note only the this month's records have been included

```
2020-07-06 11:05:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:05:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:05:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:05:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:05:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:05:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:05:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:05:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:05:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:05:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:05:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:05:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:05:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47064; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:05:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:05:11 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:05:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:05:11
2020-07-06 11:05:11 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47073; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:05:57
2020-07-06 11:05:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:06:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:06:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47082; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:06:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:06:08 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:06:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:06:08
2020-07-06 11:06:08 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47091; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:09:08
2020-07-06 11:09:08 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:14:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:14:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:14:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:14:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:14:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:14:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:14:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:14:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:14:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:14:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:14:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:14:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:14:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47116; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:14:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:14:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:14:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:14:59
2020-07-06 11:14:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47125; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:15:45
2020-07-06 11:15:45 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47134; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:22:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:22:02
2020-07-06 11:22:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47143; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:22:28
2020-07-06 11:22:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:23:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:23:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:23:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:23:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:23:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:23:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:23:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:23:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:23:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:23:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:23:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:23:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:23:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47152; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:23:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:23:40 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:23:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:23:40
2020-07-06 11:23:41 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47161; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:24:03
2020-07-06 11:24:04 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:24:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:24:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:24:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:24:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:24:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:24:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:24:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47170; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:24:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:24:35
2020-07-06 11:24:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47179; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:24:51
2020-07-06 11:24:51 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=11452
2020-07-06 11:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:27:03 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47055; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:50:52
2020-07-06 11:50:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:51:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:51:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:51:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:51:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:51:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:51:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:51:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:51:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:51:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:51:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:51:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:51:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:51:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47064; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:51:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:51:53 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:51:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:51:53
2020-07-06 11:51:53 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47073; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:52:48
2020-07-06 11:52:48 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-06 11:56:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-06 11:56:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-06 11:56:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-06 11:56:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-06 11:56:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-06 11:56:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-06 11:56:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-06 11:56:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-06 11:56:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-06 11:56:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-06 11:56:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-06 11:56:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47082; transaction id 9
2020-07-06 11:56:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-06 11:56:46 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-06 11:56:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200706 11:56:46
2020-07-06 11:56:46 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: There might be an error log. Please look into that. You can post the same here as well for us to look into it.

Comment: hi @ATULKUMARSINGH i have updated the question

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another mysql service running consuming the same port? Moreover, can you please look into the mysql error log for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: yes , i have re updated my question

Comment: Can you please check your task managar and verify whether you already have any running instance of mysql, check for the process named "mysqld.exe"?

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH I have updatd the question, and yes I already killed mysqld process

Comment: I can't see any issue logged in the log file.

Comment: yeah but keep getting the error and server not get started

Comment: You might want to refer this for once, looks like an issue somewhat similar to that of yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767200/cant-run-xampp-mysql.

Comment: yeah that has worked!

Comment: Feeling good for being of any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue due to port blocking

MySql generally starts server on port 3306 which can be used by some other programs like Skype. Ensure you change the port number.

Initially ensure that no program is using port 3306 by starting Task Manager → Services → Check program using port 3306 and terminate (generally it is not related to OS)
If the above checking is done then simply open XAMPP Control Panel → MySql config → my.ini → replace port 3306 to 3307 or 3308 (free port).
Expand window → Config at right top → Service and port settings → MySql → Main Port → 3307 (assume) → Save
Go to XAMPP folder wherever it is installed → htdocs → php → php file (configuration type) → replace port 3306 to 3307 → start the server from control panel and check if it works perfectly fine or not.

Comment: This isn't the issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem and also tried to change the port and deleting some files but never I could run the xampp correctly even reinstalling didn't help me.
Then I found a solution that helps me all the time.

Install VCRUNTIME140.DLL both 32bit and 64bit versions. Then try to run the xampp. Hope that It will work fine.