# How to fix "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly."?

Tags: mysql

So when i try to start mysql on xampp i get this error:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

When I check the loggs it says this:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 1157675541; transaction id 297601
InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201129 14:58:23
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Issue may be due to port blocking

MySql generally starts server on port 3306 which can be used by some other programs like Skype. Ensure you change the port number.

Initially ensure that no program is using port 3306 by starting Task Manager → Services → Check program using port 3306 and terminate (generally it is not related to OS) If the above checking is done then simply open XAMPP Control Panel → MySql config → my.ini → replace port 3306 to 3307 or 3308 (free port). Expand window → Config at right top → Service and port settings → MySql → Main Port → 3307 (assume) → Save Go to XAMPP folder wherever it is installed → htdocs → php → php file (configuration type) → replace port 3306 to 3307 → start the server from control panel and check if it works perfectly fine or not.

Comment: The problem is that it worked before.  I just transfered my wordpress files to a web host provider by using ftp servers. And after that it has given me this error.

Comment: In that case you may like to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767200/cant-run-xampp-mysql this is something similar as of urs

Comment: You may also check if there is already running instance of MySQL from your previous attempt