# Cannot connect mySQL Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

Help!
I am trying to connect to mySQL through XAMPP but every time I try I get the same error:

```
7:57:51 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
7:57:51 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:57:51 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:57:51 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:57:51 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:57:51 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
7:57:51 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Also this is the information in the error log:

```
2023-06-18 19:57:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-06-18 19:57:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-06-18 19:57:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-06-18 19:57:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-06-18 19:57:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-06-18 19:57:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1,                          chunk size = 16M
2023-06-18 19:57:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-06-18 19:57:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-06-18 19:57:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-06-18 19:57:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB.       Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-06-18 19:57:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-06-18 19:57:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-06-18 19:57:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.27 started; log sequence number 11914054; transaction id 20402
2023-06-18 19:57:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from   C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-06-18 19:57:50 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-06-18 19:57:50 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I've tried changing the port on my.ini to 3307/3309/3310 but I get the same error (I've tried changing it on the next lines: "

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = 
port=3307
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=3307
```

Let me know if you have any more ideas thank you!

Comment: `Physically writing the file full` - i doubt we have port problem here. make your error readable and don't just dump them as question. do you have adequate disk space?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run XAMPP - MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767200/cant-run-xampp-mysql). the solution provided in that question is similar to [this](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=82523&p=278033) - so it might be a common issue for mysql shutdown absuers.

Comment: @BagusTesa Thank you!  [This](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=82523&p=278033) has a comment with the instructions I needed! thank you a lot for sharing!