# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly XAMPP

Tags: mysql

```
[mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
[mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
[mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
[mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
[mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
[mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
[mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

I have Used recommended solution [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

But result showing same.
Can Anyone help?

Thanks In Advance
S K Setia

Comment: Hi, try the following: "Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues"

Comment: @RolandStarke, Thanks Sir

Comment: I've got the same problem, I restarted PC after uninstalling a software then this problem comes to me. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40957320/9070934) helps me.

Answer (score 2):

i did the following
C:\xampp\mysql\data -> multi-master.info

remove content from file and restart mysql

Comment: I tried every solution provided on the internet none of the work but this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Man, if you have MySQL server install and running, stop it. The error occured because of conflicting MariaDB and the other server.

Answer (score 0):

xampp->mysql->data
cut all files from data folder
and paste to another folder

now restart mysql

paste all folders from your folder to myslq->data folder

and also paste ib_logfile0.ib_logfile1 , ibdata1 into data folder from your folder.

your database and your data is now available in phpmyadmin..

Comment: This is not working...I have the same issue, i review with netsat , the port.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

**Check MySQL Error Log**

1. Start MySQL on XAMPP Control panel.
2. Check the My SQL Error log “mysql_error.log” by clicking on the Logs button on XAMPP control panel.
3. Go to the “data” directory in the mysql database. I installed XAMPP on D: drive on my computer & the mysql “data” directory location of my computer was “D:\xampp\mysql\data\”. You may have different location.

**Take Backup of MySQL “data” Folder**

1. First of all you should create a backup of the “data” folder using any compression software.
2. Give a name like “data_backup.zip” or any type of compression you wish.
   I used winrar compression software to compress & backup mysql “data” folder.

**Rename the “data” folder**

1. Rename the “data” folder to “data-oldfiles”.
2. This is very important to rename the data directory to any new directory name.

**Create a new “data” folder**

1. Create a new folder and give the folder name as “data“
2. To solve the problem we need to create a new “data” directory in the mysql database.
   **Copy content from “backup” folder**
3. Go to the “backup” folder and copy all files.
4. Paste the files from backup folder to data folder
5. Now start the MySQL database from XAMPP.
6. Now, your MySQL database will start properly without showing any error.

**Transfer all MySQL projects Database, Data file & Log files**

1. If you have many database which was used for various projects, then you have to transfer all database from “data-oldfiles” folder to “data” folder.
2. Copy all databases from the data-old files and paste to the data folder.
3. Now you have to copy the data file “ibdata1” & all log files “ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 ” from data-old files folder to the data folder. If you have many id_logiles then copied all of them.
4. MySQL error This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
   **Start MySQL from XAMPP**
5. Now Start MySQL from XAMPP.
6. Go to phpMyAdmin to check all databases are available & working.
7. Now start your any website project from localhost to check the MySQL database.
   **The Problem is solved:**
   Now you will see the problem is solved and the error message “Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.” will not show again.
   If you have any question on this issue please feel free to ask any question in the comments section.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to fix this issue with the all methods in 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly).
But they didn't fix my issue.
In my case, I solved with this way ~ 
***Firstly***:  In the XAMPP control panel, press the 'Config' button and after that press 'my.ini'.
***Secondly***:  In this "my.ini" file, find the drive-path.
   [Change Drive path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3eO0.png)
   I installed xampp on "C:\xamp" , but in the "my.ini" file all the paths were started 
   with "E:\xamp..." So I replaced "E:\xampp" with "C:\xamp".
   Because I had installed xampp on "E:\xamp" long time ago.
***Thirdly*** . And then restart the xampp.
   "**WoW**~" ***it was fixed!!!***