# How to upgrade MariaDB within Xampp

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, mariadb

I want to upgrade to MariaDB 10.2 and I'm using xampp ( I like that mysqld.exe runs in the background and easy On/Off with a single click ). What happens is that the latest version as of now is 3.2.2 and it has MariaDB 10.1.29 comes with it.
I'm looking for a general healthy way to do it.
I've tried [those steps](https://medium.com/@meness/steps-to-upgrade-mariadb-for-xampp-7924326731d3) that pretty much look good :

- Unzipping/installing the new MariaDB then copying the data directory and the config|bat files + phpMyAdmin from the old to the new installation.
  After starting for an instant, it shuts down complaining :

> ```
> 13:44:33  [main]  Control Panel Ready
> 13:52:46  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
> 13:52:46  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
> 13:52:49  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
> 13:52:49  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
> 13:52:49  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
> 13:52:49  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
> 13:52:49  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
> 13:52:49  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
> 13:52:49  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
> 13:52:49  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
> ```

### Notes:

- I'm not gonna try [some random deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly) that are very likely to
  make my db tables corrupt (even though I did before and it didn't
  work)
- Please take notice that if I run the server itself using an unprivileged user
  (not administrator) on the command line, it runs as expected.
  Furthermore, the status in the Xampp control panel would change to green :

> `14:00:35  [mysql]    Status change detected: running`

And I could even shut down the MySQL server from it, by clicking on stop.

- If I run Xampp as administrator (which could be a bad idea), I get the same error message above.
- Please note also that running MySQL server as an administrator involves security risks.
- I know I can run it as a service, but I'd rather like to have instant control over when to turn it On/Off.

### The purpose :

Looking for a clean way to upgrade MariaDB within xampp, on windows (Windows7)

Comment: Have you tried running the MariaDB 10.2.x .msi installer?

Comment: @O.Jones, yes I did. same results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, how I resolved it was:

- Re-installed MariaDB to the x32 version because I installed the x64 first
- Copied "my-huge.ini" from "C:\xampp\mysql" to "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini"

Now everything works as expected, start/stop everything is smooth. I guess there is some specific setting that is not quite correct on the old "my.ini" from XAMMP.

Of course, all this was done after I did these steps:

- Be sure all modules are stopped from the XAMPP Control Panel
- Downloaded an installer of the latest stable version of MariaDB
- Renamed "C:\xampp\mysql" to "C:\xampp\mysql_old"
- Installed the downloaded MariaDB to "C:\xampp\mysql"
- Copied the following directories to maintain my databases:

  - C:\xampp\mysql\data
  - C:\xampp\mysql\scripts
  - C:\xampp\mysql\share

Run Apache and MySQL module from the XAMPP Control Panel, and done.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I would create dumps  of existing databases and uninstall current xampp installation then download newest version of xampp which will of course contain a newer version of mariadb

Comment: That's the most obvious solution and he most likely tried it because he said he had the latest version. To this day the latest version of XAMPP is still not on MariaDB 10.2.