# MySQL keeps crashing when using xampp

Tags: xampp

I have recently started with web-development. I need a good server to run PHP and mySQL applications. The problem I am facing now is that mySQL keeps crashing whenever I open xampp. I have read most of the threads on StackOverflow and have also reconfigured the ports, deleted the ibdata1 and crash files from C://xampp/mysql/data but still nothing happens. The log data and error codes are as follows:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:11:09  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:11:09  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:11:09  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:11:09  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:11:09  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:11:09  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

and the data from mysqlerror.log is as follows:

```
2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1835037
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2018-06-02 12:11:04 d74 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-06-02 12:11:04 d74  InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
 InnoDB: Operation read to file D:\win32-packages\build\src\storage\xtradb\os\os0file.cc and at line 3216
2018-06-02 12:11:04 3444 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 287. Cannot continue operation
180602 12:11:04 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.32-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1001
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787129 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
mysqld.exe!?compare_ulonglong@@YAHPB_K0@Z()
mysqld.exe!thd_key_delete()
mysqld.exe!?compare_ulonglong@@YAHPB_K0@Z()
mysqld.exe!?free_frm_image@TABLE_SHARE@@QAEXPBE@Z()
mysqld.exe!?free_frm_image@TABLE_SHARE@@QAEXPBE@Z()
mysqld.exe!?free_frm_image@TABLE_SHARE@@QAEXPBE@Z()
mysqld.exe!?compare_ulonglong@@YAHPB_K0@Z()
mysqld.exe!?set_result_field@Item@@UAEXPAVField@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?init_net_server_extension@@YAXPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPAPAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAHPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlValidSecurityDescriptor()
ntdll.dll!RtlValidSecurityDescriptor()
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice when you post any issue include software version you are using
Please try this

- Step 1: `exit Xampp server`
- Step 2: `go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory`
- Step 3: `delete the ibdata1 file`
- Step 4: `restart xampp server`

If it's not working in Step 3: you can also delete this `ib_logfile0`

Credit [Cratos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670487/kratos)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859561/12131849