# Xampp MySQL not starting - “MYSQL not starting on XAMPP 3.2.1 version…”

Tags: mysql, xampp

i installed xampp version 3.2.1 on my laptop and mysql was working fine on it before but suddenly mysql stopped working while apache and others were working.
when i click on start mysql it displays this error
i use windows 10

```
8:52:32 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
8:52:40 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
8:52:40 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
8:52:40 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:52:40 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:52:40 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:52:40 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:52:40 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
8:52:40 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

then i checked the log file and this is what i found there

`

```
2018-06-23 08:52:32 2354 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
180623  8:52:32 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
180623  8:52:33 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 1600924
180623  8:52:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
180623  8:52:33 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
180623  8:52:33 [Warning] 'db' entry 'size of datafile is: 1907       should be: 1760

180409 15:17:15 [error] mysql.db: got error: 0 when reading datafile at record: 3

180409 15:17:15 [error] got an error from unknown thread, ha _myisam.cc:952

180409 15:17:15 [Warning] Recove@80409 15:17:15 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\mysql\db'

180409 15:17:15 [ERROR] mysql.db: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly

180409 15:17:15 [ERROR] mysql.db:' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_A
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
180623  8:52:33 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
180623  8:52:33 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--log-basename=#' or '--relay-log=mysql-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
180623  8:52:33 [Note] Started replication for '180401 18:51:15 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
'
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Master '180401 18:51:15 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist, Internal MariaDB error code: 1146
180623  8:52:33 [Note] Master '180401 18:51:15 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-180401@002018@003a51@003a15@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.000095' position: 4
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Master '180401 18:51:15 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Failed to open the relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-version@003a@0020@002710@002e0@002e17@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.000036' (relay_log_pos 4)
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Master '180401 18:51:15 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist, Internal MariaDB error code: 1146
180623  8:52:33 [Note] Master '180401 18:51:15 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Could not find target log during relay log initialization
180623  8:52:33 [Note] Master '180401 18:51:15 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Initialized Master_info from 'master-version@003a@0020@002710@002e0@002e17@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info' failed
180623  8:52:33 [Warning] Reading of some Master_info entries failed
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
180623  8:52:33 [ERROR] Aborting

180623  8:52:33 [Note] Master '180401 18:51:15 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Error reading relay log event: slave SQL thread was killed
180623  8:52:33 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
180623  8:52:33 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
180623  8:52:35 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1600934
180623  8:52:35 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete`
```

Comment: "Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run mysql_upgrade to create it" - maybe you need to run mysql_upgrade?

Comment: how can i run mysql_upgrade

Comment: This command must be in your mysql installation.

Answer (score 34):

Deleting all files (no folders!) in the /mysql/data folder, except /mysql/data/my.ini and /data/ibdata1 helped in my case.

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me too, but I have no idea what caused it.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. It would be great if you could elaborate what's happened though

Answer (score 13):

Deleting all `master-*` files and `multi-master.info` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Copying files and folders from `C:\xampp\mysql\backup` to `C:\xampp\mysql\data`
and removing all my database folders worked for me.
But first try without deleting your database files.

Answer (score 2):

Go to C:\xampp\mysql\data and delete all master files.
`multi-master`
`master-version`

Answer (score 1):

I've just ran into the same exact problem and if you have anything similar in your **mysql log file** (that looks like in the OP's question), the only thing as stated by LouzinDeev will work and should be enough.

> Go to `C:\xampp\mysql\data` and delete all master files. multi-master
> master-version

As I wondered why's this happening at the first place, and just wanted this to never happen, I did some research, so it might be useful for you to follow this practices.

**Why is this even happening?**

> **1. Incorrect Replication Configuration**
>
> - Misconfigured Settings: The most common cause is incorrect replication
>   settings in your my.cnf or my.ini file. If the master-user setting is
>   empty or not correctly configured, the slave server will attempt to
>   connect to the master with invalid credentials.
> - Accidental Changes: Unintentional edits or corruption of the
>   configuration file can lead to invalid settings.

> **2. Corrupted Replication Files File Corruption:**
>
> - The files that store replication status and settings, like master.info or relay-log.info,
>   can become corrupted due to various reasons like unexpected shutdowns,
>   disk issues, or software bugs.
> - Improper Shutdowns: Improper shutdown
>   of the database server can lead to partial writes or corruption of
>   these files.

> **3. Version Mismatches or Upgrades**
>
> - Upgrading Issues: Upgrading MariaDB/MySQL without properly migrating or updating the replication setup can lead to inconsistencies in the
>   replication configuration.
> - Version Incompatibility: Sometimes, replication issues arise due to incompatibilities between different versions of MariaDB/MySQL used on
>   master and slave servers.

> **4. Permission Issues**
>
> - User Privileges: If the replication user does not have the correct privileges on the master server, it can lead to errors during
>   connection attempts.
> - Server Security Settings: Security settings on the master server that restrict connections can also be a factor.

> **5. Manual Intervention or Human Error**
>
> - Unintentional Deletion or Modification: Accidental deletion or modification of critical replication files or settings by users or
>   administrators.
> - Improper Setup: Errors in setting up replication, especially in a complex environment with multiple slaves or multi-master setups.

***So, as conclusion in order to avoid this type of problems (as prevention and best practices):***

> - Regular Backups: Regularly back up your databases and configuration files.
> - Careful Configuration: Be meticulous when editing configuration files; keeping comments or documentation of changes is helpful.
> - Monitoring and Logs: Regularly monitor the database logs for any signs of issues.
> - Proper Shutdown Procedures: Ensure that the database server is always properly shut down.
> - Keep Software Updated: Regularly update MariaDB/MySQL to the latest stable version to avoid bugs.
> - Test Configurations: In a non-production environment, test changes to the replication setup before applying them in the production
>   environment.

> **Why Deleting Master Files Fixes the Issue**
>
> - Replication Configuration Files: In a MariaDB/MySQL setup, certain files in the data directory (like master.info and other related files)
>   store information about replication settings. If these files become
>   corrupted or are misconfigured, it can prevent the database server
>   from starting correctly.
> - Reset Replication Settings: Deleting these files removes the corrupted or incorrect replication settings. When MariaDB restarts,
>   **it no longer attempts to establish a problematic replication connection.**

**Important Considerations**

- Replication Configuration: If you are using replication intentionally, you will need to reconfigure it correctly after deleting these files.
- Data Safety: Always make sure to have backups of your important data before making changes to the database system.

As I said at the beginning, this is only for the type of error which is similar or same to the OP's error log, if you have something which looks like this:

```
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-08-02 12:19:12 f64 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1616798 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-08-02 12:19:12 4536 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
```

You should [visit this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71369592/12826055) as it is probably going to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete mysql.pid file.
you can delete also other master-* files