# why mySql can not starting?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Why can't mysql run when I click on Start? I changed the port in `my.ini` to 8855 but it does not run again !!

> [mysql] Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. [mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, [mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. [mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues [mysql] If you need more help, copy and post this [mysql] entire log window on the forums

mySql_error.log:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp7.4\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp7.4\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.14 started; log sequence number 3780062; transaction id 1658
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp7.4\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-01-22 14:19:45 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.info'
2021-01-22 14:19:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210122 14:19:46
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--log-basename=#' or '--relay-log=mysql-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.info'
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
' to hash table
2021-01-22 14:19:46 8 [Note] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Started replication for '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
'
2021-01-22 14:19:46 9 [Note] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.000001' position: 4
2021-01-22 14:19:46 8 [ERROR] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info'
2021-01-22 14:19:46 8 [Note] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
2021-01-22 14:19:46 8 [Note] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [ERROR] Failed to open the relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.000001' (relay_log_pos 4)
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [ERROR] Could not find target log during relay log initialization
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [ERROR] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info' failed
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
' to hash table
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp7@002e4@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp7@002e4@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info'
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp7@002e4@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info'
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] c:\xampp7.4\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
' to hash table
2021-01-22 14:19:46 10 [Note] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] c:\xampp7.4\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Started replication for '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] c:\xampp7.4\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
'
2021-01-22 14:19:46 11 [Note] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] c:\xampp7.4\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d12@002d28@002010@003a58@003a14@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp7@002e4@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.000001' position: 4
2021-01-22 14:19:46 10 [ERROR] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] c:\xampp7.4\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
2021-01-22 14:19:46 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e14@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e14@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info'
2021-01-22 14:19:46 10 [Note] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] c:\xampp7.4\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
2021-01-22 14:19:46 10 [Note] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] c:\xampp7.4\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
2021-01-22 14:19:47 7 [ERROR] log .\mysql-relay-bin-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e14@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020.4.14-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4
 listed in the index, but failed to stat
2021-01-22 14:19:47 7 [ERROR] Error counting relay log space
2021-01-22 14:19:47 7 [ERROR] Initialized Master_info from 'master-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e14@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info' failed
2021-01-22 14:19:47 7 [Note] Added new Master_info 'Version: '10.4.14-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
' to hash table
2021-01-22 14:19:47 0 [Warning] Reading of some Master_info entries failed
2021-01-22 14:19:47 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
2021-01-22 14:19:47 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Warning: Memory not freed: 16864
```

Comment: "Press the Logs button to view error logs and check [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues"

Comment: Have you looked at the details in the "error logs" and "Windows Event Viewer". It may give hints on what's wrong. It's hard to know what's causing your error if I can't get more details

Comment: "If you need more help, copy and post this [mysql] _entire_ log window", it really says "ENTIRE LOG" ?

Comment: @Luuk I put the log can you help me?

Comment: @RaanaTashakori:If you do NOT post the log, no one can help your....

Comment: The warning `[Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used;` is noted, because you seem to have a Master/Slave setup, for some reason this setup is not correct (`[ERROR] Master '2020-12-28 10:58:14 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593`)

Comment: Because i do not know anything about your data (and if you have a backup), I hesitate  to send you to a [Question about this problem without Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999358/xampp-mysql-not-starting-mysql-not-starting-on-xampp-3-2-1-version), so a proper warning: "If you have data that you do not want to loose, find another solution!"