# When I installed XAMPP Server, it could not connect to MySQL

Tags: xampp

```
11:43:34 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:43:34 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:43:34 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:43:34 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:43:34 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clue`enter code here`s
11:43:34 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
11:43:34 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
1) Exit XAMPP Server
2) Go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
3) Delete the ibdata1 file
4) Restart XAMPP Server

To look for further answers, go to: 
[XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)