# Xampp Mysql not running MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp

When i try to run xampp using control panel MySQL shutdown unexpectedly i check log file and found this also i try to delete temp files in mysql/data/ after delete my xampp start working but my all database crashes every time i delete temp files.... i am using windows 10 64bit... please help me

```
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
c:\xampp5\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2018-11-30 12:18:23 2c38 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-11-30 12:18:23 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 49463
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1600624
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.25 started; log sequence number 1600624
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3307
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2018-11-30 12:18:24 3520 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: I Think you default **Mysql's** database is missing. Remove the xamp and reinstall and check.

Comment: Maybe this can help you... https://xuri.me/2014/11/09/slove-mysql-plugin-federated-is-disabled.html