# XAMPP MySQL service crash after reboot

Tags: mysql, xampp

I just installed an XAMPP 7.3.6-2-VC15 for Windows, 64 bit, and when I install it, it's fine. MySQL start from the control panel without error, etc. All is OK.

After rebooting my PC, Apache is still working, but MySQL refuses to start! I try to reinstall XAMPP, but it's exactly the same. MySQL works fine, and stops working after reboot.

Here are the few logs I have...

In the control panel:

```
09:48:10  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
09:48:10  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
09:48:11  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
09:48:11  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
09:48:11  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
09:48:11  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
09:48:11  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
09:48:11  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
09:48:11  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
09:48:11  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

And in the log file:

```
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=1834407
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1834416; transaction id 265
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190702  9:48:10
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-07-02  9:48:10 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I try the following:

- Change port for other than 3306 => no success
- Run xamp control panel as admin => no success
- remove temporary table ibdata1 and ibtmp1 => no success

If someone have an idea...

I try to install as a windows service via the administrator panel as administrator. And so, I have some new lines in log. It seems the user table is corrupted... How can I repair it?

```
2019-07-02 10:04:41 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\user' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2019-07-02 10:04:41 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Index for table '.\mysql\user' is corrupt; try to repair it
2019-07-02 10:04:41 0 [ERROR] Couldn't repair table: mysql.user
2019-07-02 10:04:41 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Index for table 'user' is corrupt; try to repair it
```

Comment: _Small Point_ `10.3.16` probably means this is mariaDB and not MySQL

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlcheck/

Comment: Following your comment, i try this  : C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqlcheck.exe: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when trying to connect.

Comment: You've found a bug. If it happens again [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57212238/2376004) will save you having to re-install.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This one helped for me:

Open shell from from control panel and start mysql with this command:

```
mysqld –-console –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking
```

Open another shell from control panel and repair database with this command:

```
mysqlcheck -r --databases mysql --use-frm
```

Stop mysql, close shells and restart mysql normally.

Based on: [Re: Corrupt mysql.users How to fix](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,652134,652135#msg-652135)

Comment: I finally rebuild from scratch, so i cannot try your solution. But it seems to be a good way...

Comment: I am always coming here back while testing locally, and this solution works a charm every single time. Nice work

Answer (score 28):

I got this problem like you . I have solved this problem like below.

`Copy from xampp/mysql/backup folder and paste in xampp/mysql/data folder except ibdata1 file.`

If you replace ibdata1 file from xampp/mysql/data then some database you will get error table does not exist.

Comment: Copied only "multi-master.info" and it worked, no idea why.

Comment: That worked for me-- everything else failed.

Comment: Had this issue occurred many times, but still don't know why this solution works haha

Comment: Thank you very much, you are my hero, thanks a lot