# Xamp wont start MySQL

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to start the mysql service. I tried deleting some ibdata file as said in other posts but that didn't solve my issue. My error log is as follow:

2020-06-08 17:10:27 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Index for table '.\mysql\db' is corrupt; try to repair it
2020-06-08 17:10:27 0 [ERROR] Couldn't repair table: mysql.db
2020-06-08 17:10:27 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Index for table 'db' is corrupt; try to repair it

Can someone help?

Comment: What triggered the issue? Do you have backup?

Comment: I don't know what triggered the issue I normally opened it as I do always and then the error occurred. No but its not a lot of data in the database so it wouldn't be heartbreaking loss.

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128891/how-repair-corrupt-xampp-mysql-user-table