# How do I repair corrupt mysql.db

Tags: mysql

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
18:31:15  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
18:31:15  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    

Getting this in logs:
    InnoDB: using atomic writes.
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 47064; transaction id 9
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200827 18:31:08
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

The Error section:

```
2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Index for table '.\mysql\db' is corrupt; try to repair it
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [ERROR] Couldn't repair table: mysql.db
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Index for table 'db' is corrupt; try to repair it
    2020-08-27 18:31:08 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Sounds like [mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and should be repaired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58386240/mysqld-exe-table-mysql-db-is-marked-as-crashed-and-should-be-repaired).

Comment: Tagging sql server will not help you find answers.

Comment: please pay attention to relevancy when you tag. I've removed [tag:apache], [tag:sql-server] and [tag:xampp]. Also, voting to close as off-topic (see [help/on-topic]) as this question is not programming related. Please look for an appropriate site in the stackexchange network. When you carry over the question: Please add description (read [ask]) instead of just posting log output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and should be repaired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58386240/mysqld-exe-table-mysql-db-is-marked-as-crashed-and-should-be-repaired)