# Mysql shuts down from Xampp when I start it

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, mariadb

it started everything today when I was going to grant privileges from root to another user from MySql (MariaDB).
Then I got "ERROR 1034 (HY000): Index for table 'db' is corrupt; try to repair it", I tried the command
repair table mysql.db and the connection with the localhost failed. Then Mysql crashed for the first time. I tried multiple times to restart it but it shutdowns constantly. I also tried to reboot my computer to check if some ports were occupied but the situation still lasts.
What can I do?
Thank you in advance

edit:

error log:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 1853753; transaction id 2559
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-24 13:23:05 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Sounds like a table corruption. Look at the mysql error log and ALSO the Windows Event Viewer (if you are on windows). Then show us what the actual errors are. ___Edit you're question, dont paste that as a comment___

Comment: There are no ERRORS in that piece of the log

Comment: this is what i get every time i try to start mysql
the first error i found is this:
2019-11-24 12:52:59 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Index for table '.\mysql\db' is corrupt; try to repair it

***WARNING: .\mysql\db could not be opened: Error: 126
 10% 26% 41% 57% 72% 95% 100% (0.0 seconds); tables to flush: 1 0
 (0.0 seconds); 
2019-11-24 12:52:59 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: recovery done

Comment: But that looks like a normal - Good restart. Can you look at the Windows Event Viewer for messages from MYSQL

Comment: I solved unistalling and reinstalling Xampp

Thank you!

Comment: This solves the issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847804/xampp-mysql-service-crash-after-reboot