# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. XAMPP, how to repair a corrupt table

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have been researching this issue for 2 days now and all the questions and answers do not solve my problem.

Found! in the mysql_error.log after running it several times:

> 2020-01-06 16:34:11 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\user' is
> marked as  crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
>
> 2020-01-06 16:34:11 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege  tables:
> Table '.\mysql\user' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?)
> repair failed

So now I see the issue after numerous times trying to start MySQL and reviewing the log, this time I finally see the "user" table is corrupt.

Can anyone advise how to repair this?

Comment: do you have a backup from your database?

Comment: Yes I do, can I copy that and overwrite the bad file?   Is the file ibdata1?  it's in c:\xampp\mysql\data

Comment: I don't know if you can replace the database as a file. Do you have a backup in SQL? If the table is beyond repair you can `drop table` then `create table` from a backup.

Comment: @jack.sparrow Can you advise the process for doing that?  not sure how to perform this.

Answer (score 16):

First, from XAMPP control panel, open "Config" [mysql] and add the
following line under [mysqld] = innodb_force_recovery = 1

then do the following:

Open shell from control panel and start mysql with this command:

```
mysqld –-console –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking
Open another shell from control panel and repair database with this command:
mysqlcheck -r --databases mysql --use-frm
Stop mysql, close shells and restart mysql normally.
```

IF it doesn't work then change innodb_force_recovery = 2 and repeat process, and again if that doesn't work, change to 3, etc... up to 4

You can find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847804/xampp-mysql-service-crash-after-reboot) useful

Comment: after running the first line in directory where corrupt table is, it ran and at the end of the run it says:   [ERROR] mysqld: Table '.\mysql\user' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed  - should I have run this in \mysql directory?

Comment: Hi @JRse, make sure you Stop the MySQL daemon/service by executing the command- `service mysql stop`.   then run – `myisamchk -r table_name`. you can follow the link [link] (https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/mysql-table-is-marked-as-crashed-and-last-repair-failed/).

Comment: It gave me an error when I ran myisamchk -r user.....  says File 'user' doesn't exist??    I ran it from dir xampp\mysql.       my database is InnoDB could this be why?

Comment: I went to the site [link you provided] and tried to run some of the commands and it is telling me I do not have permission to use *.MYI?    I am at the command prompt, any idea on how to get permission?

Comment: @Lelio I ran   mysqld –-console –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking and seemed to work, but was unable to do anything at the prompt after that.  So I started another shell [command prompt] and ran  mysqlcheck –repair mysql user...   it returned the following:   Failed to SHOW CREATE TABLE 'user'     Error:  Table '.\mysql\user'  is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

Comment: OK... just now looked at XAMPP Control Panel and see MySQL running???  not sure what made that happen....    wow, interesting.  I did start it earlier as Admin but did not see it running then.   I'm thinking it happened after following the link you provided and ran a few things... wish I had looked up after executing those.  I will try to bring up my program to see if all is OK.

Comment: I pulled this from the XAMPP Control Panel:      

10:22:19 AM  [mysql]  Status change detected: running     THIS last line shows the time it came back up

Comment: OK.. the minute I tried run my program on "Brackets" it failed again and is shutting down again..

Comment: @Lelio I ran at the command prompt again:     mysqld –-console –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking, and watched the XAMPP Control Panel, this is what started MySQL.  It is running again.  But in the log file on one of the lines it shows:     2020-01-07 10:57:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=184980007.     But the rest of the log does not show anything bad or failing.

Comment: OK, I tried to run another program and also phpmyadmin and get the folowing error:     This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost phpmyadmin
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: Edit your /etc/my.cnf and add:
 innodb_force_recovery = 1  . Try [link] (https://serverfault.com/questions/592793/mysql-crashed-and-wont-start-up#).

Comment: @JRse Also see mysql_install_db [options]. Do u have some backup?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205562/discussion-between-ashish-mishra-and-jrse).

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that these two commands were successful for me. `mysqlcheck` fixed lots of wrong CRCs on the `mysql.db` datapages.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this answer in an unclear form here on stackOverflow which helped me, hope this answer helps too

1 - open the directory "c:/xampp/mysql/data" and remove the folder "mysql"

2 - now you will copy the "mysql" folder from "c:/xampp/mysql/backup" and then paste it in the "c:/xampp/mysql/data" directory

Hope this answer helps!

Comment: This will only help if the problem is in the mysql database only. If other databases are corrupt it won't.

Answer (score 0):

As XAMPP forcefully shutsdown the database process sooner or later this is bound to happen.

Considering you are running windows (from the `\` I deduce you are) there are a couple of steps you could try to repair this.

1. rename `c:\xampp\mysql\data` to something else (data_YYMMDD)
2. copy `c:\xampp\mysql\backup` to `c:\xampp\mysql\data`
3. try to see of MariaDB starts (it should) and stop it.
4. copy over InnoDB folders from `c:\xampp\mysql\data_YYMMDD` to `c:\xampp\mysql\data`
5. run c:\xampp\mysql\mysqlcheck.exe --auto-repair --all-databases -uroot

Btw. any user accounts you created will be lost and will have to be recreated.

Comment: *"As XAMPP forcefully shutsdown the database process sooner or later this is bound to happen.*" - Out of curiosity, because I didn't know about that: Is this a known fact? Could you provide a source for this statement?

Comment: The code is avaible as batch shell commands. It locates the process ID and performs a taskkill. Not something I would do to a running database process

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. So, XAMPP is indeed using `taskkill /F` (=forced) to stop the MySQL process... WOW.

For the records: the above mentioned batch files are `mysql_stop.bat` and `killprocess.bat` in the XAMPP root folder.