# xaamp MySql server wont start

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have been using this for a few days with no issue but yesterday the mysql server refused to start. I have rebooted everything and it is still doing the same thing. Here is part of the log file. Please let me know how to get it back up and running and why it is doing this? This is windows 10 operating systems. Also, Apache server still starts fine.

```
**InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-11-24 15:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-11-24 15:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-11-24 15:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-11-24 15:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-11-24 15:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-11-24 15:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-11-24 15:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-11-24 15:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.16 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 170
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201124 15:25:24
2020-11-24 15:25:24 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-11-24 19:42:47 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: starting recovery
recovered pages: 0% 13% 55% 81% 94% 100% (0.0 seconds); tables to flush: 2 1 0
 (0.1 seconds); 
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: recovery done
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=458268
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.16 started; log sequence number 458277; transaction id 670
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-11-24 19:42:48 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=458587
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.16 started; log sequence number 458596; transaction id 693
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-11-25 11:28:55 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.**
```

Comment: no this looks ok hat you can see at `Server socket created on IP: '::'. ` and there is no coause to see why it is startung gain, else there would be an error message. mysql isn't to blame here, some else is restarting the computer whioch forces  mysql to recover

Comment: That is very strange. I am on personal computer and no one else can access it. Any ideas as to what could be causing this? It appears mysql starts for a1-2 seconds before stopping.

Comment: check the logs for any errors(not the mysql ) and chekc the dates from the mysql log that fit

Comment: I found one. Here it is...

Comment: 2020-11-27 14:29:06 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Index for table '.\mysql\db' is corrupt; try to repair it

***WARNING: .\mysql\db could not be opened: Error: 126
 25% 35% 48% 62% 74% 86% 96% 100% (0.0 seconds); tables to flush: 3 2 1 0
 (0.3 seconds);

Comment: no that is after the system crahsed or some thing, mysql likes to be correctly terminated and this doesn't happen. so it starts new, and find that it has to recover from something, nut when mysql is the cause you see 1ß-20 entrys with errors and description

Comment: That is the only thing that resembles any kind of error

Comment: check the system logs what happens at the restart time

Comment: I resolved it. I will post solution below. I have no idea why it worked though. Need to investigate. Thanks for your help. Checking the log for the error got me to the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy from xampp/mysql/backup folder and paste in xampp/mysql/data folder except ibdata1 file.

If you replace ibdata1 file from xampp/mysql/data then some database you will get error table does not exist.

found this here...
[XAMPP MySQL service crash after reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847804/xampp-mysql-service-crash-after-reboot)