# how to fix mysql from xampp shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, database

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

i have installed xampp in computer server and one month went well without any problems but this time i got error when start the mysql service i check the error log and try to search solution in internet and no one can fix this itry to move backup folder to data in mysql folder this work but when i open database and select some table return error table not exist

this my error log

```
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full;Please wait ...
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2019-08-01 10:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2019-08-01 10:48:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.15 started; log sequence number 1604126; transaction id 9
    2019-08-01 10:48:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
    2019-08-01 10:48:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190801 10:48:06
    2019-08-01 10:48:06 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2019-08-01 10:48:06 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: I've tried it and other solutions by replacing the data with the data in the backup folder the xamp can run again but my database is corrupt and I can't open all the tables