# Cannot start MySQL service

Tags: mysql

I've tried to open Services and start MySQL service but it doesn't let me do that for some reason. I've googled the error and it said to do something like
`$ mysqld --install`
`$ mysqld --initialize`
Please Help.

[image]

Comment: Did you check that some program is not using the port ? do you have skype installed ? Check that a particular program is not using the mysql port, most likely a recent installation.

Comment: Find and read the error log from mysql.  It will say why it didn't start.

Comment: @NicholasMberev I do not have Skype installed. I used this `netstat -ano -p tcp` to find out which ports are being used and the port 3306 was not in use which is the port that MySQL uses. I saw something saying that if you don't have the `my.ini` file in the data or bin folder I need to add it. I added it but it was empty. I don't know if I should have pasted anything into it or not.

Comment: I am perceiving that you have some corrupted installation of xampp ???? If so, then you need to back up your data and install a new clean version of it directly from apachefriends.org

Comment: See how you can take safe backup here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389529/physically-writing-the-file-full-mysql-error/62702953#62702953

Comment: @NicholasMberev I've reinstalled XAMPP, still nothing is working

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:52:00 PM  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:52:00 PM  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:52:00 PM  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:52:00 PM  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:52:00 PM  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
10:52:00 PM  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly