# I've got this problem all of a sudden with mysql after restart the laptop

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

When I try to run mysql server on Apache server on application Xampp
this error message appears. I've got this problem all of a sudden.

I tried to change the port of mysql but it did not work.

> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port,
>   missing dependencies,  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
>   another method. Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the
>   Windows Event Viewer for more clues If you need more help, copy and
>   post this entire log window on the forums

when I open my sql errors Log i see ..

```
Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
Uses event mutexes
Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
Number of pools: 1
Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
Completed initialization of buffer pool
128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
Waiting for purge to start
10.3.16 started; log sequence number 14508144; [enter image description here][1]transaction id 14742
Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: didn't work ...