# XAMPP MySQL shutdown unexpectedly - no error in logs

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp

XAMPP was working correctly earlier this morning, but after doing some Wordpress plugin updates and resyncing with Github and Pantheon, MySQL now will start, run for a few seconds, and then shut down. When looking at mysql_error.log, I see this:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 113917; transaction id 9
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191009 12:41:23
2019-10-09 12:41:23 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I don't see any obvious errors.

Any thoughts on how I could either get more detailed error information or how to fix this? Thanks!

***UPDATE***

In the Windows Event Viewer, I was able to get the following error description:

```
Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
```

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18162264/4061713

Comment: I tried that and then I tried also deleting the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files as well. No difference.

Comment: Since I couldn't find a solution, I went ahead and uninstalled and reinstalled xampp. The new installation is working perfectly.

Comment: There is newer and probably better (? because it does not delete ibdata1, which is endangers your data?) answer to the question originally linked by @earid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859561/2466193.

Answer (score 4):

Copy this files:

```
aria_log.00000001
aria_log_control
ib_buffer_pool
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
ibdata1
ibtmp1
multi-master.info
```

from: xampp\mysql\backup

to: xampp\mysql\data

UPDATE after 3 years: It's probably file multi-master.info. You can move this file from backup folder to data folder. Btw. it's obvious doing backups for everyone file. I recomended uising docker, i think xampp isn't good solution for production

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for the advice. Since posting, I ended up switching to WAMPServer and will eventually be doing all development using Docker container instances to avoid this type of headache (although I know Docker config isn't without it's own headaches either). Anyways, thanks again for taking the time to look through my logs and offer your help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Igor L I had this exact same issue and moving these files did the trick. Anyone know what causes this issue?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859561/2466193 is very similar in what it does, but probably a little bit better as it does not delete your ibdata1 (potentially dangerous?) and makes an 'OLD' copy of your valuable data first (so you can roll back if the fix fails).

Comment: UPDATE: It's probably file multi-master.info. You can move this file from backup folder to data folder. Btw. it's obvious doing backups for everyone file.