# XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly after importing a .sql file

Tags: mysql, xampp

Yesterday, I tried to import some .sql file (basic, fully-working). After I did so, I immediately lost my mysql connection. My first move was to just restart it through xampp control panel, but it didnt work, and gave me an error:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
3:14:34 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:14:34 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:14:34 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:14:34 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:14:34 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
3:14:34 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

I cannot make it start. I already tried changing port number, installing fresh xampp (but there was another issue with importing database (innoDB)). So, I have a clean xampp instalation now, and a backup of a previous one - how can I at least manage to restore my data?

Logs does not contain any error line.

Comment: Did you check if something else was using port 3306? `netstat -aon`

Comment: Is this on Windows or a linux

Comment: Like do you have another MySQL Server installed, Normally if you do it autostarts and beat XAMPPs MySQL to the port

Comment: I did check netstat, port 3306 is not listed. It is a windows, and I do not have another MySQL server installed.

Comment: SO its not a port block, as its windows privilages are very unlikely, as it did work missing dependancies are unlikely. So its probably a corrupted database.so try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly I am assuming you do not have any other databases!!!!

Comment: I have tried that already. And i do have copuple more databases (just databases, not whole servers), but I care about just one of them. In result of actions taken by that link you gave me - whenever I Was trying to open any of my tables, I was getting error like 'table_name does not exist in engine' (If I remember that correctly), BUT, except for two tables, which was based on MyISAM (other ones, which are not working are based on InnoDB)

Comment: That makes sense, MYISAM  as all held in the sunfolder with that name of the database, But INNODB datbases have parts of themselves in the `ibdata1` file,

Comment: Okay. But am I able to fix this? Or at least restore data?