# MySQL Shutdown Unexpectedly even after changing port of Mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp

When i am starting mySQL in XAMPP it is showing me this error.
Yesterday it was working fine. I have also installed composer yesterday.
I am using php version 7.3 (Latest One)

```
9:35:30 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
9:35:30 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
9:35:32 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
9:35:32 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
9:35:32 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:35:32 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:35:32 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:35:32 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:35:32 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
9:35:32 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

I have tried to change the port of mySQL in my.ini file from 3306 to 8111 and then run it as an administrator but it still shows the same error.
I also tried to delete ibdata1 file but still it is not working for me.
I have used the composer for the very first time so i was just thinking may be it is due to the composer. As i have installed it in a developer mode. But i also delete the composer folder from appdata/roaming/composer

Comment: What did the logs say?

Comment: you can get help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: Don't go deleteing mysql files. That will make sure it doesn't start. Reading logs and understanding them is a good idea.