# XAMPP- MYSQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am facing this problem from today morning .

```
    11:30:25 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    11:30:25 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    11:30:25 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    11:30:25 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    11:30:25 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    11:30:25 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
    11:30:25 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

following is error log

```
    [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\mysql\gtid_slave_pos.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``mysql`.`gtid_slave_pos``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `mysql`.`gtid_slave_pos` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``mysql`.`innodb_index_stats``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `mysql`.`innodb_index_stats` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\mysql\innodb_table_stats.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``mysql`.`innodb_table_stats``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\mysql\transaction_registry.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``mysql`.`transaction_registry``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `mysql`.`transaction_registry` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__bookmark.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__bookmark``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__bookmark` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__central_columns.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__central_columns``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__central_columns` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__column_info.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__column_info``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__column_info` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__designer_settings.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__designer_settings``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__designer_settings` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__export_templates.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__export_templates``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__export_templates` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__favorite.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__favorite``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__favorite` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__history.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__history``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__history` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__navigationhiding.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__navigationhiding``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__navigationhiding` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__pdf_pages.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__pdf_pages``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__pdf_pages` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__recent.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__recent``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__recent` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__relation.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__relation``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__relation` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__savedsearches.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__savedsearches``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__savedsearches` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__table_coords.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__table_coords``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__table_coords` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__table_info.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__table_info``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__table_info` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__table_uiprefs.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__table_uiprefs``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__table_uiprefs` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__tracking.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__userconfig.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__usergroups.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__usergroups``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__usergroups` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\phpmyadmin\pma__users.ibd' OS error: 71
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``phpmyadmin`.`pma__users``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `phpmyadmin`.`pma__users` because it could not be opened.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 7246905; transaction id 25896
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191204 10:57:26
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
    2019-12-04 10:57:26 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I tried deleting ibdata1 file. and also replacing  mysql/backup folder files into data folder. But those changes were leading to other errors. so I revert it.
It was giving 'Table doesn't exist in engine' error for many of my tables

Please help out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on the view that you try Re-Installing XAMPP because it might have been corrupted.

But Before Re-installing first Uninstall the existing XAMP but remember to backup all your databases then delete the XAMP folder.
Hope this will help.