# MYSQL shutdown unexpectedly in XAMPP control panel

Tags: mysql, xampp

When am trying to start Mysql, am getting the below error:

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues. If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums

Error log: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YW0YqRSpc6s1NneRaoSq8CuWWKemJ9um_9xtM4Z6nTY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must change mysql port 
please follow the path below

```
\xampp\mysql\bin
```

open `my.ini` by some editor and change port

for example :

```
port=3309
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

change it to

```
port=3306
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

Comment: I cant see other port than 3306. The below is port in config file:

port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"

Comment: @Chiranth change port , if now is 3306 change it to 3309

Comment: @Chiranth two time you must change in this file first search port keyword and thene change it and reset you xamp

Comment: now Goto xampp>phpMyAdmin Directory.

Find the config.inc.php file.

Now change this line:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';

Comment: 127.0.0.1:3307 or 127.0.0.1:3309?

Comment: @Chiranth you must try other to find empty port for mysql and change it . finally change listener in config.inc.php