# Laravel 5.4 xampp localhost Mysql automatically stops

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, localhost

actually I am working on the laravel 5.4 application. Actually the main problem is that whenever I click on the button of the application [admin dashboard] for example (view employe details) then after a little browsing xampp MySQL automatically turns off. I have traced this error but got no results yet.

[here you can see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMmB5.png)

after a lot of loading page, it shows ( this site can't be reached ) although the same code with the same DB is working fine on my co-worker laptop. The code and routes are working perfectly.

http://localhost:82/carehalo_mini/public/view_employess  (this is route example. Hope you got my point

Comment: Probably this is related to Xampp not your code, check "logs" of Mysql, the summary of error log in the screenshot you shard says that you might have a port blocked ( possibly by another app)

Comment: This might be because the port is blocked by some other program. To confirm, you can check the error logs.

Comment: The error above happens when you try to insert two rows with the same 'id', leave 'id' field empty, it will be incremented automatically.
But I don't think this error is causing Mysql to shut down

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Actually, it say says delete the ibtmp1 file in the xampp SQL folder. I have tried it yesterday but that's also never worked for me. Secondly, I have also changed the port number multiple times no results at all.

Comment: Try : `netstat -na | find "3306"`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/26564/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-blocked-on-a-windows-machine

Comment: This thread has suggested solutions, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: thanks a lot everyone for the contribution.