# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly [XAMPP]

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

I'm using XAMPP on Windows 10. a few days ago, MySQL Service has been stopped suddenly and it is no longer possible to run.

I've deleted mysql\data\ibdata1 file[[like this]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18162264/8591502) and didn't work. Changed default ports[[like this]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53083691/8591502) but it didn't work too. I copied the xampp/mysql directory and pasted it on another computer, but unfortunately the mysql service didn't run there either.

Thanks for your help.

**more information:**

[XAMPP Control Panel ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24r2w.jpg)

mysql_error.log :

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 2G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\htdocs0\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\htdocs0\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 113881; transaction id 9
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\htdocs0\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200607 12:12:22
2020-06-07 12:12:22 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

my.ini :

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = your_password 
port=3306
socket="D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=3306
socket="D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql"
tmpdir="D:/xampp/htdocs0/tmp"
datadir="D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer=1600M
max_allowed_packet=2000M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir="D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql/lib/plugin/"

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id    =1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "D:/xampp/htdocs0/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir="D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1600M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="D:/xampp/htdocs0/mysql/share/charsets"
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16000M

[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]


query_cache_size = 268435456
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 1048576
```

Comment: I had this problem too. I couldn't find any solution, so I installed [WAMPP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/). I instantly liked it better and I wouldn't want to change back!

Comment: Use Windows Task Manager to see if MySQL is already a running SERVICE, please.  If you find it running, just STOP it and try again.

Comment: Is D: rotating media, thumb drive, SSD ? what is the type of storage?