# xampp cannot start MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

I shut down my `xampp` to take a lunch break and for some reason I cannot start it up again. When I try to launch `MySQL` it says the following:

```
13:13:19  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
13:13:19  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:13:19  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:13:19  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:13:19  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:13:19  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
13:13:19  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

So I check the error logs:

```
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 702532; transaction id 2087
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-11-25 13:13:17 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

What am I doing wrong / how can I fix this issue?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldnt find the answer myself as I was focused on the line "Plugin FEEDBACK is disabled"

Comment: Do you by any chance have another instance of MySQL server running? Maybe try changing ports?

Comment: You already helped me with the article above :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [A R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7506896/a-r) I found the solution:

I had to stop `MySQL`, copy the `data` folder and remove the files that have the `INFO File` type.