# How to get MySql data from files without phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, xampp

My MySql was not working for 2 hours in xampp.

My logs are

```
01:37:11  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
01:37:11  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
01:37:11  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
01:37:11  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
01:37:11  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
01:37:11  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
01:37:11  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

I have tried almost everything and nothing is working for me and I think I have also made my xampp settings even worse.

So now I will delete xampp and install again.

But wait, my databases are very important.

So is there by which I reinstall xampp and also I have all the databases I need.

I can't start MySql
I can't access phpMyAdmin

So how can I save my data from files?

Comment: Why was MySQL not working? Did you check the logs?? Its always best to try and fix these things rather than throw everything away and start again

Comment: Are your database(s) MYISAM or INNODB?

Comment: @RiggsFolly don't know I never noticed, what type of databases they are, I have just started PHP and mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: @YunfeiChen I tried it, nothing worked.

Comment: If we know what you have tried _I have tried almost everything_ we could suggest other things. So what have you tried

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried changing MySQL my.ini files as shown in Videos and I also tried changing config.inc files as shown in Videos, but nothing worked

Comment: Have you looked in the Windows Event Viewer for more information? Show us the error s from MYSQL from there

Answer (score 0):

Good luck trying "open your SQL files" (whatever those are).

The answers as to why MySQL is not running are in your log files.

Yes, you can back up the data files and restore them into a new installation.

We can't tell you where those files are - it [depends on how you installed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/windows-installation-layout.html) MySQL. This might be defined in C:\Windows\my.ini (you're looking for files named .ibd and .frm).

Make sure the MySQL service is stopped. Move the directory containing these file out of the way, then remove and reinstall MySQL. After that stop the (newly installed MySQL service) [edit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/windows-troubleshooting.html) C:\Windows\my.ini to set the datadir to the ,oved files, and start mysql.

Answer (score -1):

You should open your sql files and look at the data, if it looks fine you can copy your backup folder into a recovery disk like F and reinstall it than copy the backup into your new data and replace new data with your backup you just copied, if the data is corrupt, well you need to go and try: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/myisam-table-maintenance.html But the thing is if it does not work than most likely you need to force INNODB reboots......

Comment: Which sql files? Which data? Please explain it

Comment: You know in your xampp, you have the mysql folder right?? When you go inside, you will find the backup folder, check the files in that folder...... and see if they are corrupt if no you are good to go and reinstall this business....

Comment: This backup folder have some folder and files [Image of backup folder](https://snipboard.io/az6ChP.jpg)

Comment: Yep copy the whole thing, all the images and folder and files...

Comment: @YunfeiChen after that Can I reinstall xampp again, and then where I have to put the files which I copied from backup.

Comment: @Vinayak you put them inside your current, make sure you dont forget to make a backup of your old data folder as well, the one that litterally says data, then put your backup in your backup and your data into your new data folder../...