# Probably MySQL ibdata1 is corrupted

Tags: mysql, xampp

Logs:

```
2020-12-07 13:53:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-12-07 13:53:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-12-07 13:53:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-12-07 13:53:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-12-07 13:53:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-12-07 13:53:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-12-07 13:53:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-12-07 13:53:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*5242880 to 2*104857600 bytes; LSN=47064
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 104857600 bytes
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 104857600 bytes
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=47064
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47064; transaction id 9
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201207 13:53:33
2020-12-07 13:53:33 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Fail:

```
13:57:48  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
13:57:48  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:57:48  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:57:48  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:57:48  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:57:48  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
13:57:48  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums+
```

I tried run mysqld.exe, move mysql/backup to data and copy old_data/ibdata1 to data and copy database folders to data/, result: same

Comment: Did you ___check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues___

Comment: You dont tell us what `mysql/backup` is or what or when `old_data/ibdata1` was created and how it relates to the current state etc etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly 2nd answer @RiggsFolly

Comment: Just checking: Are your databases INNODB or MYISAM?

Comment: Windows Event Viewer fail: Reading of some Master_info entries failed

I tried remove multi-master.info but this time fail is ... not exists on engine

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't now, but I guess innodb

Comment: Maybe your issue is a broken OS

Comment: in my opinion broked ibdata1 because I tried mysql/back move to mysql/data and worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)