# Mysql is shuts down unexpectedly on Xampp

Tags: php, xampp

this is my issue please help me to solve this problem ...
6:25:59 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
6:25:59 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
6:25:59 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
6:25:59 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
6:25:59 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
6:25:59 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
6:25:59 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

```
 in the error log file is show me this .....



 InnoDB: using atomic writes.
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk 
    size = 16M
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xamppnew\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. 
    Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xamppnew\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.16 started; log sequence number 47090; transaction id 8
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from 
    C:\xamppnew\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210503  6:25:51
    2021-05-03  6:25:51 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide relevant details with your question. Please read and edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a duplicate for this question.

Please refer to the link below as there is answer available for it.

[MySql shuts down unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)