# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly in XAMPP(v3.2.4) while Apache is working fine

Tags: mysql, xampp

The MySQL in XAMPP has been working fine for weeks, today suddenly I got the error "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly."

**Error on Xampp Panel:-**

```
12:21:51 PM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:21:51 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:21:51 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:21:51 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:21:51 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:21:51 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
12:21:51 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

**Error in Log file:-**

```
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 7819084880; transaction id 25239
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210525 12:01:07
2021-05-25 12:01:07 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I tried many solutions but no one worked for me

**Solution 1:-**

```
Run MySQL with XAMPP shell with command : 
mysqld –-console –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking
```

**Ref:** https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=79154

**When I tried above given solution, got following log in shell**

```
 2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.17-MariaDB) starting as process 16280 ...
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-05-25 12:44:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-05-25 12:44:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 7819084979; transaction id 25239
2021-05-25 12:44:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-05-25 12:44:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-05-25 12:44:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210525 12:44:27
2021-05-25 12:44:27 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-05-25 12:44:27 6 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1932: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.info'
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--log-basename=#' or '--relay-log=mysql-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.info'
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2021-05-24 21:27:04 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succ' to hash table
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Started replication for '2021-05-24 21:27:04 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries su'ceeded
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.000024' position: 4
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info'
': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4ntries succeeded
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master:04 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4e] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info'
' to hash table4:27 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2021-05-24 21:27:04 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Started replication for '2021-05-24 21:27:04 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash tabl'
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.000024' position: 4
': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020d@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020d@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info'
': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4 hash table
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master7:04 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4te] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020d@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info'
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2021-05-24 21:27:04 0 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready fo' to hash table
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Started replication for '2021-05-24 21:27:04 0 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready 'or connections.
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a27@003a04@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020d@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.000024' position: 4
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e17@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e17@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info'
2021-05-25 12:44:27 12 [ERROR] Master '2021-05-24 21:27:04 0 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2021-05-25 12:44:27 13 [ERROR] Master '2021-05-24 21:27:04 0 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4xe: ready for connections.2021-05-25 12:44:27 12 [ERROR] Master '2021-05-24 21:27:04 0 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master7:04 0 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4te] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e17@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info'
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Added new Master_info 'Version: '10.4.17-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org bina' to hash table
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Started replication for 'Version: '10.4.17-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org bi'ary distribution
2021-05-25 12:44:27 15 [Note] Master 'Version: '10.4.17-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distributio': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e17@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.000049' position: 4
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a17@00208@0020@005berror@005d@0020innodb@003a@0020table@0020@0060mysql@0060@002e@0060innodb_table_stats@0060@0020not@0020found@002e@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a17@00208@0020@005berror@005d@0020innodb@003a@0020table@0020@0060mysql@0060@002e@0060innodb_table_stats@0060@0020not@0020found@002e@000d.info'
2021-05-25 12:44:27 14 [ERROR] Master 'Version: '10.4.17-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distributi': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2021-05-25 12:44:27 15 [ERROR] Master 'Version: '10.4.17-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distributi': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2021-05-25 12:44:27 14 [Note] Master 'Version: '10.4.17-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distributio': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4
2021-05-25 12:44:27 14 [ERROR] Master 'Version: '10.4.17-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distributi': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
2021-05-25 12:44:27 14 [Note] Master 'Version: '10.4.17-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distributio': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
2021-05-25 12:44:27 14 [Note] Master 'Version: '10.4.17-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distributio': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a17@00208@0020@005berror@005d@0020innodb@003a@0020table@0020@0060mysql@0060@002e@0060innodb_table_stats@0060@0020not@0020found@002e@000d.info'
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2021-05-24 21:28:17 8 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_st' to hash table
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Started replication for '2021-05-24 21:28:17 8 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_'tats` not found.
2021-05-25 12:44:27 17 [Note] Master '2021-05-24 21:28:17 8 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not found': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a17@00208@0020@005berror@005d@0020innodb@003a@0020table@0020@0060mysql@0060@002e@0060innodb_table_stats@0060@0020not@0020found@002e@000d.000024' position: 4
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a27@002031@0020@005berror@005d@0020mysqld@002eexe@003a@0020table@0020@0027@002e@005cvrdapi@005cfair_settings@0027@0020is@0020marked@0020as@0020crashed@0020and@0020should@0020be@0020repaired@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a27@002031@0020@005berror@005d@0020mysqld@002eexe@003a@0020table@0020@0027@002e@005cvrdapi@005cfair_settings@0027@0020is@0020marked@0020as@0020crashed@0020and@0020should@0020be@0020repaired@000d.info'
2021-05-25 12:44:27 16 [ERROR] Master '2021-05-24 21:28:17 8 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not foun': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2021-05-25 12:44:27 17 [ERROR] Master '2021-05-24 21:28:17 8 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not foun': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [ERROR] Failed to create a new master info file (file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a27@002031@0020@005berror@005d@0020mysqld@002eexe@003a@0020table@0020@0027@002e@005cvrdapi@005cfair_settings@0027@0020is@0020marked@0020as@0020crashed@0020and@0020should@0020be@0020repaired@000d.info', errno 2)
2021-05-25 12:44:27 16 [Note] Master '2021-05-24 21:28:17 8 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not found': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [ERROR] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a27@002031@0020@005berror@005d@0020mysqld@002eexe@003a@0020table@0020@0027@002e@005cvrdapi@005cfair_settings@0027@0020is@0020marked@0020as@0020crashed@0020and@0020should@0020be@0020repaired@000d.info' failed
2021-05-25 12:44:27 16 [ERROR] Master '2021-05-24 21:28:17 8 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not foun': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2021-05-24 21:28:27 31 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\vrdapi\fair_sett' to hash table as crashed and should be repaired
2021-05-25 12:44:27 16 [Note] Master '2021-05-24 21:28:17 8 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not found': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a27@002031@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cvrdapi@005cfair_settings@0027@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a27@002031@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cvrdapi@005cfair_settings@0027@000d.info'
2021-05-25 12:44:27 16 [Note] Master '2021-05-24 21:28:17 8 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not found': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a27@002031@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cvrdapi@005cfair_settings@0027@000d.info'
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2021-05-24 21:28:27 31 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\vrdapi\fair_se' to hash table
2021-05-25 12:44:27 7 [Note] Started replication for '2021-05-24 21:28:27 31 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\vrdapi\fair_'ettings'
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2021@002d05@002d24@002021@003a28@003a27@002031@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005cvrdapi@005cfair_settings@0027@000d.000024' position: 4
': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2021-05-25 12:44:27 0 [Warning] Reading of some Master_info entries failed
': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4dapi\fair_settings'
': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2021-05-25 12:44:27 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
2021-05-25 12:44:27 0 [ERROR] Aborting
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master8:27 31 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\vrdapi\fair_settings'
```

**Solution 2:-**

```
1-Rename the folder xampp/mysql/data to xampp/mysql/data_old (you can use any name)
2-Create a new folder xampp/mysql/data
3-Copy the content that resides in xampp/mysql/backup to the new xampp/mysql/data folder
4-Copy all your database folders that are in mysql/data_old to mysql/data (except mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders from data_old)
5-Now copy the ibdata1 file from xampp/mysql/data_old and replace it inside xampp/mysql/data folder
You can start MySQL again from control panel now
```

**Ref:** https://www.quora.com/MySQL-shutdown-unexpectedly-in-XAMPP-How-can-I-fix-it

**Solution 3:-**

```
1-exit Xampp server
2-go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
3-delete the ibdata1 file
4-restart xampp server
```

**Ref:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/18162264/14108430

**Solution 4:-**

```
Changed MySQL port from 3306 to 8111
```

In this way, I tried many solutions but no one worked for me, any help will be appreciated.

**PS:** Is there any way that MySQL runs properly without deleting my DB?

Comment: Check the ports you are using, it seems its in use. Disable all virus scanners etc. to see if that helps.

Comment: changed port from 3306 to 8111 but not working

Comment: Wrong username, Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593

Comment: Since this question is not about programming, it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO can help with database admin related questions like this one. The error message indicates that your replication config is incorrect, so pls make sure you mention this in your question on the DBA site.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution 1 log says: **[ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures** so just delete the multi-master.info : location **C:\xampp\mysql\data** then restart the xampp and mysql server