# XAMPP cannot start MySQL (No applications running on same port)

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have been using XAMPP/MySQL with no problems for a few weeks now. I even started XAMPP/MySQL today with no problems. I closed it, and now a few hours later I open it and it is giving me this error. I have tried restarting my PC and looked to see if any applications were running on port 3306 (none were found)

```
7:23:06 pm  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.                     
7:23:06 pm  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,       
7:23:06 pm  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.       
7:23:06 pm  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check      
7:23:06 pm  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues        
7:23:06 pm  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this       
7:23:06 pm  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

[The logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxVT4.jpg)

Comment: possible duplicate [xampp mysql shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issues before ..
what I did was that, I Installed a Clean version of XAMPP form its official Website.

- I suggest you uninstall the current XAMPP server also Make sure to
  Delete any lingering XAMM related documents before Installing the New
  Copy.