# XAMPP Control Panel v 3.3.0 - Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Tried to start my Apache server today and MySQL is not running, this is the error that it shows:

```
10:15:28 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
10:15:32 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
10:15:32 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:15:32 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:15:32 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:15:32 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:15:32 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:15:32 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:15:32 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

This is the log error from the xampp control panel:

```
2021-06-10 10:15:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-06-10 10:15:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-06-10 10:15:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-06-10 10:15:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-06-10 10:15:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-06-10 10:15:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-06-10 10:15:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-06-10 10:15:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-06-10 10:15:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-06-10 10:15:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-06-10 10:15:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-06-10 10:15:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-06-10 10:15:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.19 started; log sequence number 47133; transaction id 8
2021-06-10 10:15:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-06-10 10:15:29 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-06-10 10:15:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210610 10:15:29
2021-06-10 10:15:29 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Tried to:

1. Rename the folder `mysql/data` to `mysql/data_old` (you can use any name)
2. Create a new folder `mysql/data`
3. Copy the content that resides in `mysql/backup` to the new `mysql/data` folder
4. Copy all your database folders that are in `mysql/data_old` to `mysql/data` (skipping the `mysql`, `performance_schema`, and `phpmyadmin` folders from `data_old`)
5. Finally copy the ibdata1 file from `mysql/data_old` and replace it inside `mysql/data` folder
6. Start MySQL from the XAMPP Control Panel

Also tried:

1. Exit the Xampp Server
2. Go to your `C:\xampp\mysql\data` directory
3. Delete the `ibdata1` file
4. Restart Xampp server

Who knows the solution?

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone will be interested in the answer, just reinstalled the xammp control panel since it was still giving me errors

Answer (score 0):

btw for future reference this can happen when you shut down your computer with xampp still running.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I always close xampp before shutting down my pc. I don't know what triggered this error

Comment: Also for future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: Thank you, I have tried all the solutions from there first, it still did not work for me