# Xampp shows MySQL shutdown unexpectedly; isn't working unless every time of reinstalling xampp,

Tags: mysql, xampp

My Xampp server is showing "MySQL shutdown unexpectedly". I did follow some solution to this problem but still it doesn't fix. All I have to do is every time I have to use MYSQL I uninstall and reinstall Xampp and thus it works. But need a proper demonstration and solve for the problem I am facing. It's tedious to reinstall every time.

Tried the following the solve from this thread. [Stackoverflow_Fabrizio_Valencia_Solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

- Rename the folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old (you can use any name)
- Create a new folder mysql/data
- Copy the content that resides in mysql/backup to the new
  mysql/data folder
- Copy all your database folders that are in mysql/data_old to
  mysql/data (skipping the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin
  folders from data_old)
- Finally copy the ibdata1 file from mysql/data_old and replace
  it inside mysql/data folder
- Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel

Will be grateful if anyone helps me get through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Xampp as administrator and then re-downloading Apache and MySQL works.
Figured out the solution. Nevertheless, Thanks to the great community!

Answer (score -1):

Please check your anti-virus may be its interrupting the xampp and also the port that xampp is using may be used by some other programs. Skype interferes with XAMPP and WAMP on port 80 so install any port checking tool and figure out which program is causing the issue.

I Hope that your problem will be solved by addressing this.

Comment: Apache and mysql are two different pieces of software!

Comment: Do this
1- Run XAMPP Using Administrator Privileges
2- Change your mySql Port

Comment: @BabarSajjad I did try this procedure as well. But didn't work out :/ Also, I am not using any anti-virus.

Comment: @BabarSajjad running as Administrator works now. And I had to reinstall Apache and mySql. Thanks!