# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly in XAMPP SERVER

Tags: mysql, server, xampp, localhost

I was working on XAMPP server. I have done my work yesterday and open my system today. Now, when I start MySQL from the XAMPP control panel, I then receive errors:

```
 Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
5:49:38 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
5:49:38 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:49:38 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:49:38 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:49:38 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
5:49:38 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

MySQL log file - MySQL errors

```
2021-08-23 17:49:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-08-23 17:49:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-08-23 17:49:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-08-23 17:49:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-08-23 17:49:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-08-23 17:49:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-08-23 17:49:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-08-23 17:49:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-08-23 17:49:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-08-23 17:49:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-08-23 17:49:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-08-23 17:49:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-08-23 17:49:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 47242; transaction id 9
2021-08-23 17:49:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-08-23 17:49:36 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-08-23 17:49:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210823 17:49:36
2021-08-23 17:49:36 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

It was working cool yesterday. I didn't do anything yesterday.
I tried solution -
[How can I solve "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

After tried the solution, it's working, but many tables do not exist in the engine.
Like - `Table 'database.meditemimg' doesn't exist in engine`.

I have 10 tables in my database. Three tables exist, but 7 tables do not exist after applied this method:

```
Rename the folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old (you can use any name)
Create a new folder mysql/data
Copy the content that resides in mysql/backup to the new mysql/data folder
Copy all your database folders that are in mysql/data_old to mysql/data (skipping the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders from data_old)
Finally copy the ibdata1 file from mysql/data_old and replace it inside mysql/data folder
Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel
```

The collation changed to in use for 7 tables.

Is there another way to fix the MySQL shutdown error?

Comment: your log shows a running server and no error where logged, so maybe the server rebotteor made an update

Comment: Ok now, How can I get my data to save and fix the MySQL shutdown error?

Comment: your server is running, acording to the log you shown, so a simple mysq - root -p works. you can chekc the saystem logs to see if there was a problem, but you can access yourdata

Comment: How to do that? I am not getting it.

Comment: windows has an event viewer, where everything is logged look for the time of the shutdown if there is something unusual and make always backups, so that in all cases you restore a working dataabse

Comment: I have taken the backup of my folder MySQL.   I have seen windows event viewer. There are many errors showing in local - MariaDB has 24 errors in the last hour. Also other apps. how can I fix that ?

Comment: that is no programming question , yu could try it at superuser, but you can already look up he erros by lookkin g at the deatil and search for it, also you should chekcm the harddrive for errors

Comment: ok, I'll try myself.

Comment: did you pay attention to these sections?

Copy all your database folders that are in mysql/data_old to mysql/data (skipping the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders from data_old)
Finally copy the ibdata1 file from mysql/data_old and replace it inside mysql/data folder

Comment: The last block is copied from [Rasul Ebrahimzadeh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-can-i-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/65047764#65047764) (or an answer that plagiarises it).

Answer (score 0):

Instead, first try using the MySQL backup folder which is included with XAMPP. So do next steps:

1. Rename folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old
2. Make a copy of mysql/backup folder and name it as mysql/data
3. Copy all your database folders from mysql/data_old into mysql/data
   (except mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders)
4. Copy mysql/data_old/ibdata1 file into mysql/data folder
5. Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel

Answer (score -1):

- 1.intially load Apache Sever properly then after that click on "Start" Mysql
  2.If you again face the same the issue then
  3.click "Config" on Mysql server from Xampp control panel , then paste this line

"skip-grant-tables" (command)

it should look like this:

```
  # Here follows entries for some specific programs 
  # The MySQL server
  default-character-set=utf8mb4
  [mysqld]
  skip-grant-tables //here place the line
  port=3306
  socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

- 4.Again restart it , it should work properly.. Thanks.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that this is a permission problem?